# How do I get the hash for the current commit in Git?

Tags: git, git-hash

How do I get the hash of the current commit in Git?

Comment: Use `git log` to retrieve recent commits, that will show full commit hash

Comment: Useful question! I was able to use this in a build script: `"record_commit_hash_and_build_time": "now=$(date -u \"+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\") && last_commit=$(git rev-parse HEAD) && echo \"{\\\"commit\\\": \\\"$last_commit\\\", \\\"build_time\\\": \\\"$now\\\"}\" > frontend/dist/version.json",` https://stackoverflow.com/a/11493416/470749

Answer (score 3951, accepted):

To turn any extended object reference into a hash, use **[`git-rev-parse`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse)**:

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

or

```
git rev-parse --verify HEAD
```

To retrieve the short hash:

```
git rev-parse --short HEAD
```

To turn *references* (e.g. *branches and tags*) into hashes, use `git show-ref` and `git for-each-ref`.

Comment: `--verify` implies that: `The parameter given must be usable as a single, valid object name. Otherwise barf and abort.`

Comment: `git rev-parse --short HEAD` returns the short version of the hash, just in case anyone was wondering.

Comment: Adding to what Thane said, you can also add a specific length to `--short`, such as `--short=12`, to get a specific number of digits from the hash.

Comment: @TysonPhalp: `--short=N` is about **minimal** number of digits; git uses larger number of digits if shortened one would be undistinguishable from shortened other commit.  Try e.g. `git rev-parse --short=2 HEAD` or `git log --oneline --abbrev=2`.

Comment: Adding to what Thane, Tyson, and Jakub said, you can print the full hash, but highlight the hexits necessary to identify the commit blue with `git rev-parse HEAD | GREP_COLORS='ms=34;1' grep $(git rev-parse --short=0 HEAD)`

Comment: Neat trick Zaz. It doesn't seem to work with the grep on my Mac, but I substituted `ack` for a similar effect!

Comment: @Zaz That didn't work for me either, but simply `git rev-parse HEAD | grep --color $(git rev-parse --short=0 HEAD)` does.

Comment: Is there a way to do this but on a per-directory basis? For example, lets say I want the latest hash of a particular directory. Do I need to do a `git log <directory>` and parse it out to grab the hash?

Comment: @Aaron: roughly speaking yes, you need to run `git log <options> -- <directory>`; but you can configure git-log so it returns only hash.

Comment: Adding to what @ThaneBrimhall said, you can get the full SHA-1 reference from the short version of the hash using `git rev-parse ca003ae`.

Comment: Does this way work if you have a tag named "HEAD"?  >:)

Comment: @EdRandall: `git rev-parse` main goal is to parse parameters and return revisions, so `--short` means shortened SHA-1 of revision. `git log` return more information, which includes SHA-1 of revisions, that can be abbreviated with `--abbrev` or `--abbrev-commit`.

Comment: `git rev-parse HEAD | pbcopy` is great for quick clipboard’ing on mac

Comment: Cool! I have even added it to alias: `git config --global alias.sha 'rev-parse HEAD'`. Now I can simply use `git sha`.

Comment: This is answer is not always correct! If the HEAD is not at the your checkout commit (detached head) what you get back is incorrect. Only `git status` will give you the correct commit hash.

Comment: I find this doesn't work with non-annotated tags. If you have a non-annotated tag pointing to head, `git rev-parse --short HEAD` _should_ give you the same result as `git show-ref -s7 <tag>` and it doesn't I got two different hashes when doing this. This is because lightweight tags will only show their ref hash not the hash of the commit they are pointing to. You need to do `git rev-parse --short '<tag>^{}'` for that.

Comment: When do I need `--verify`?

Comment: @xjcl the `--verify` option is useful if you use `git rev-parse` together with something variable, like `git rev-parse --verify $branch`. For `git rev-parse --verify HEAD` it ensures that HEAD can be turned into SHA-1 / object identifier (and for example you are not on an unborn branch).

Comment: If you pass this to pbcopy on mac to copy it into the clipboard, you'll get a new line at the end. To get rid of it, use `git rev-parse HEAD | tr -d '\n' | pbcopy`

Comment: Small caveat for `git rev-parse xxx`: This results in `SHA + \n`, so it adds a new line at the very end. So if you want to get just the SHA, be sure to trim your result

Comment: Let's say that `git rev-parse --short HEAD` shows `4f5d5b9`, but `git status` is dirty. How can I make it show `4f5d5b9-dirty`, instead?

Comment: I figured it out! [Here is my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76856090/4561887) on how to print `4f5d5b9` if `git status` is clean, and `4f5d5b9-dirty` if it is dirty.

Answer (score 553):

To get the shortened commit hash, use the `%h` format specifier:

```
git log --pretty=format:'%h' -n 1
```

`%H` represents the long commit hash. Also, `-1` can be used directly in place of `-n 1`.

Comment: Or, it seems, adding --short to the rev-parse command above seems to work.

Comment: I think `git log` is porcelain and `git rev-parse` is plumbing.

Comment: One of the benefits of this method is that it will return the short version of the hash with the right length adjusted to the hash collisions which happen for larger repos. At least in recent versions of git.

Comment: This is a bad/ incorrect way of doing it because this method will give you the wrong hash if you have a detached head. For example if the current commit is 12ab34... and the previous commit was 33aa44... then if i do 'git checkout 33aa44'  and then I run your command I will still be getting back 12ab34... despite my head actually pointing to 33aa44...

Comment: @theQuestionMan I don't experience the behavior you describe; `git checkout 33aa44; git log -n 1` gives me `33aa44`. What version of git are you using?

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse if `git log` is porcelain and `git rev-parse` is plumbing, what is `git status --porcelain`? :P

Comment: @PatrickL I don't know, this is a question from 4 years ago and I don't feel like going back to something that's behind me. I recommend that you open a new question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse, ah! I HAD NO IDEA this is a toilet analogy! I've been seeing `porcelain` in the `git` `man` pages for years, but had NO idea it was referring to a toilet! The porcelain is the toilet, and it's "closer to the user" (who figuratively sits on this toilet) than the plumbing, which is lower-level and farther from the user--ie: below the "porcelain"! Mind blown.

Comment: @PatrickL, I'd say `git status` is the plastic toilet seat. It's closer to the user than the porcelain, where "porcelain" refers to the porcelain bowl under the toilet seat. So, `git status` and `git log` are plastic. `git log --pretty=format` is porcelain, `git status --porcelain` is also porcelain, and `git rev-parse` is plumbing.

Comment: Full pretty format options: https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats#Documentation/pretty-formats.txt-emHem

Answer (score 196):

Another one, using git log:

```
git log -1 --format="%H"
```

It's very similar to the of @outofculture though a bit shorter.

Comment: And the result is not single-quoted.

Comment: This is the correct answer, since it works even if you checkout a specific commit instead of `HEAD`.

Comment: @Parsa: when checking out a specific commit `HEAD` points to this commit rather than a named branche know as [detached head](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_detached_head).

Comment: From the command line, to avoid pager: `git --no-pager log -1 --format="%H"`

Comment: @Parsa Your (mistakenly upvoted?) comment is misleading as the accepted answer of jakub-narębski 'git rev-parse HEAD' works after checking out somewhere else.

Comment: @Parsa - maybe we misunderstand each other: *after* checkout from commit a1b1 to c1d1 `git rev-parse HEAD` prints c1d1. So, HEAD points to the "current commit" which the OP asked for. From your upvoted comment I mistakenly concluded that `git rev-parse HEAD` was wrong.

Answer (score 158):

To get the full SHA:

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD
cbf1b9a1be984a9f61b79a05f23b19f66d533537
```

To get the shortened version:

```
$ git rev-parse --short HEAD
cbf1b9a
```

Comment: If two `git` `commit` hashes are needed, such as one from the `branch` you are currently working with and a `master` `branch`, you could also use `git rev-parse FETCH_HEAD` if you need the hash for the `master` `commit` that you `merge`d into your current `branch`.

e.g. if you have `branch`es `master` and `feature/new-feature` for a given repo., while on `feature/new-feature` you could use `git fetch origin master && git merge FETCH_HEAD` and then `git rev-parse --short FETCH_HEAD` if you needed the `commit` hash from the `master` you just `merge`d in for any scripts you may have.

Answer (score 103):

Commit hash

```
git show -s --format=%H
```

Abbreviated commit hash

```
git show -s --format=%h
```

The `-s` flag is same as `--no-patch` and stands for "Suppress diff output".

Click [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show#_examples) for more `git show` examples.

Answer (score 95):

For completeness, since no one has suggested it yet.  `.git/refs/heads/master` is a file that contains only one line: the hash of the latest commit on `master`.  So you could just read it from there.

Or, as a command:

```
cat .git/refs/heads/master
```

---

Update:

Note that git now supports storing some head refs in the pack-ref file instead of as a file in the /refs/heads/ folder.  https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pack-refs.html

Comment: This assumes the current branch is `master`, which is not necessarily true.

Comment: Indeed. That's why I explicitly said this is for `master`.

Comment: There is `.git/HEAD` which is a file that contains 1 line with the SHA1 of HEAD. I think that's what you meant.

Comment: `.git/HEAD` typically points to a ref, if you have a SHA1 in there, you are in detached head mode.

Comment: This isn't very robust compared to other approaches, in particular because it assumes that there is a `.git` subdirectory, which is not necessarily the case. See the `--separate-git-dir` flag in the `git init` man page.

Comment: ＋1 because sometimes you don't want git executable installed (e.g. in your Dockerfile)

Comment: For finding the SHA- hash of a branch `.git/refs/heads/<branch-name> `

Comment: +1 -and- if you don't want to necessarily pull/rebase/merge and just want to get hash post-fetch `cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/master`

Comment: This is less robust because `.git` may always be a file containing the name of the real .git directory.

Comment: +1 because this may be faster and more straightforward as you don't have to call bash just to display the commit hash in the footer of the GUI.

Comment: one step further `cat .git/refs/heads/$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)`

Answer (score 62):

There's always `git describe` as well. By default it gives you --

```
john@eleanor:/dev/shm/mpd/ncmpc/pkg (master)$ git describe --always
release-0.19-11-g7a68a75
```

Comment: Git describe returns the first TAG reachable from a commit. How does this help me get the SHA?

Comment: I like `git describe --long --dirty --abbrev=10 --tags` it will give me something like `7.2.0.Final-447-g65bf4ef2d4` which is 447 commits after the 7.2.0.Final tag and the first 10 digest of the global SHA-1 at the current HEAD are "65bf4ef2d4". This is very good for version strings. With --long it will always add the count (-0-) and the hash, even if the tag happens to match exactly.

Comment: If no tags exist then `git describe --always` will "show uniquely abbreviated commit object as fallback"

Comment: I use `git describe --tags --first-parent --abbrev=11 --long --dirty --always`. The `--always` option means it provides a result (hash) even if there are no tags. The `--first-parent` means it doesn't get confused by merge commits and only follows items on the current branch. Note also that `--dirty` will append `-dirty` to the result if the current branch has uncommitted changes.

Answer (score 42):

Use `git rev-list --max-count=1 HEAD`

Comment: git-rev-list is about generating list of commit objects; it is git-rev-parse to translate object name (e.g. HEAD) into SHA-1

Answer (score 33):

If you need to store the hash in a variable during a script, you can use

```sh
last_commit=$(git rev-parse HEAD);
```

Or, if you only want the first 10 characters (like github.com does)

```sh
last_commit=$(git rev-parse --short=10 HEAD);
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to use this in a build script: `now=$(date -u "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") && last_commit=$(git rev-parse HEAD) && echo "{\"commit\": \"$last_commit\", \"build_time\": \"$now\"}" > version.json`

Answer (score 23):

If you want the super-hacky way to do it:

```bash
cat .git/`cat .git/HEAD | cut -d \  -f 2`
```

Basically, git stores the location of HEAD in .git/HEAD, in the form `ref: {path from .git}`.  This command reads that out, slices off the "ref: ", and reads out whatever file it pointed to.

This, of course, will fail in detached-head mode, as HEAD won't be "ref:...", but the hash itself - but you know, I don't think you expect that much smarts in your bash one-liners.  If you don't think semicolons are cheating, though...

```bash
HASH="ref: HEAD"; while [[ $HASH == ref\:* ]]; do HASH="$(cat ".git/$(echo $HASH | cut -d \  -f 2)")"; done; echo $HASH
```

Comment: no need to install git, I like it. (my docker build image does not have git)

Comment: also useful because you can run this easily from outside the git repo

Comment: I formalized this to a script for my local machine.  Then, I thought, hey: the implementation I made are simple enough that it illustrates how to solve an unrelated problem (parsing arguments in raw POSIX shell scripts without external programs), but complex enough to provide a little variation and to exploit most of the features of `sh`.  Half an hour of documentation comments later, and here's a Gist of it: https://gist.github.com/Fordi/29b8d6d1ef1662b306bfc2bd99151b07

Comment: Looking at it, I made a more extensive version for detecting Git and SVN, and grabbing the git hash/svn revision.  Not a clean string this time, but easily command-line parsed, and usable as a version tag:

https://gist.github.com/Fordi/8f1828efd820181f24302b292670b14e

Answer (score 23):

I needed something a little more different: display the full sha1 of the commit, but append an asterisk to the end if the working directory is not clean. Unless I wanted to use multiple commands, none of the options in the previous answers work.

Here is the one liner that does:
`git describe --always --abbrev=0 --match "NOT A TAG" --dirty="*"`
Result: `f5366ccb21588c0d7a5f7d9fa1d3f85e9f9d1ffe*`

Explanation: describes (using annotated tags) the current commit, but only with tags containing "NOT A TAG". Since tags cannot have spaces, this never matches a tag and since we want to show a result `--always`, the command falls back displaying the full (`--abbrev=0`) sha1 of the commit and it appends an asterisk if the working directory is `--dirty`.

If you don't want to append the asterisk, this works like all the other commands in the previous answers:
`git describe --always --abbrev=0 --match "NOT A TAG"`
Result: `f5366ccb21588c0d7a5f7d9fa1d3f85e9f9d1ffe`

Comment: Thanks, just stumbling over it and it spares me the one or other echo for that :)

Comment: It works for me without the `--match "NOT A TAG"`. Tested in git 2.18.0 as well as 2.7.4. Is there any situation where this argument is needed?

Comment: @Thomas it won't work if you have an annotated tag anywhere in the history of the current commit. The fake tag makes sure that the describe command does not use a tag to describe the commit,

Answer (score 20):

Perhaps you want an alias so you don't have to remember all the nifty details. After doing one of the below steps, you will be able to simply type:

```
$ git lastcommit
49c03fc679ab11534e1b4b35687b1225c365c630
```

Following up on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/949391/890242), here are two ways to set this up:

1. Teach git the explicit way by editing the global config (my original answer):

```
# open the git config editor
$ git config --global --edit
# in the alias section, add
...
[alias]
  lastcommit = rev-parse HEAD
...
```

2. Or if you like a shortcut to teach git a shortcut, as recently commented by Adrien:

   $ git config --global alias.lastcommit "rev-parse HEAD"

From here on, use `git lastcommit` to show the last commit's hash.

Answer (score 20):

`git rev-parse HEAD` does the trick.

If you need to store it to checkout back later than saving actual branch if any may be preferable:

```sh
cat .git/HEAD
```

Example output:

```
ref: refs/heads/master
```

Parse it:

```sh
cat .git/HEAD | sed "s/^.\+ \(.\+\)$/\1/g"
```

If you have Windows then you may consider using wsl.exe:

```
wsl cat .git/HEAD | wsl sed "s/^.\+ \(.\+\)$/\1/g"
```

Output:

```
refs/heads/master
```

This value may be used to git checkout later but it becomes pointing to its SHA. To make it to point to the actual current branch by its name do:

```
wsl cat .git/HEAD | wsl sed "s/^.\+ \(.\+\)$/\1/g" | wsl sed "s/^refs\///g"  | wsl sed "s/^heads\///g"
```

Output:

```
master
```

Answer (score 17):

The most succinct way I know:

```
git show --pretty=%h
```

If you want a specific number of digits of the hash you can add:

```
--abbrev=n
```

Comment: While this technically works, `git show` is what's known as a porcelain command (i.e. user-facing), and so should *not* be used in scripts because its output is subject to change. The answer above (`git rev-parse --short HEAD`) should be used instead.

Comment: @jm3 that's backwards. "Porcelain" commands have stable outputs that are intended for scripts. Search `git help show` for `porcelain`.

Comment: @JohnTyree This is a confusing subject, but jm3 was right: porcelain commands are not meant to be parsed, but rather to be human-readable. In case you need to use a porcelain command in a script and you want to have a stable format, there's sometimes (for example with git status, push and blame) an option that does just that. Unfortunately, that option is called `--porcelain`, which is why this is confusing. You can find the details in [this great answer by VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6978402/3982001)

Answer (score 12):

Here is one-liner in Bash shell using direct read from git files:

```
(head=($(<.git/HEAD)); cat .git/${head[1]})
```

<sup>You need to run above command in your git root folder.</sup>

This method can be useful when you've repository files, but `git` command has been not installed.

If won't work, check in `.git/refs/heads` folder what kind of heads do you have present.

Answer (score 9):

```
git show-ref --head --hash head
```

If you're going for speed though, [the approach mentioned by Deestan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12913817/72321)

```
cat .git/refs/heads/<branch-name>
```

is significantly faster than any other method listed here so far.

Comment: `show-ref` seems to me to be the best option for scripting, since it's a plumbing command and thus guaranteed (or at least very likely) to remain stable in future releases: other answers use `rev-parse`, `show`, `describe`, or `log`, which are all porcelain commands. And in cases where speed is *not* of the essence, the note from the `show-ref` manpage applies: ‘Use of this utility is encouraged in favor of directly accessing files under the .git directory.’

Answer (score 7):

in your home-dir  in file  ".gitconfig"  add the following

```
[alias]
sha = rev-parse HEAD
```

then you will have an easier command to remember:

```
$ git sha
59fbfdbadb43ad0b6154c982c997041e9e53b600
```

Answer (score 7):

On git bash, simply run
$ git log -1

you will see, these lines following your command.

```
commit d25c95d88a5e8b7e15ba6c925a1631a5357095db .. (info about your head)

d25c95d88a5e8b7e15ba6c925a1631a5357095db, is your SHA for last commit.
```

Answer (score 3):

Pretty print of main git repo, and sub-modules:

```bash
echo "Main GIT repo:"
echo $(git show -s --format=%H) '(main)'
echo "Sub-modules:"
git submodule status | awk '{print $1,$2}'
```

Example output:

```
3a032b0992d7786b00a8822bbcbf192326160cf9 (main)
7de695d58f427c0887b094271ba1ae77a439084f sub-module-1
58f427c0887b01ba1ae77a439084947de695d27f sub-module-2
d58f427c0887de6957b09439084f4271ba1ae77a sub-module-3
```

Answer (score 2):

How I would do it in python (based on @kenorb's bash answer)

```py
def get_git_sha():
    # Which branch are we on?
    branch = open(".git/HEAD", "r").read()

    # Parse output "ref: refs/heads/my_branch" -> my_branch
    branch = branch.strip().split("/")[-1]

    # What's the latest commit in this branch?
    return open(f".git/refs/heads/{branch}").read().strip()
```

Answer (score 2):

### Get the hash for the current commit, *and* see if `git status` is "clean" or "dirty"

I want to see `72361c8` or `72361c8-dirty` for use in my build system version numbers injected into my program executables. Here is how:

### Quick summary

```bash
# get a short commit hash, and see whether `git status` is clean or dirty
test -z "$(git status --porcelain)" \
    && echo "$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)" \
    || echo "$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)-dirty"
```

Sample output when `git status` is clean (there are *no* uncommitted changes):

```
72361c8
```

Sample output when `git status` is dirty (there are *any* uncommitted changes):

- Meaning: there are *any* uncommitted changes, whether they are unstaged changes to tracked files, staged (`git add`ed) changes to tracked files, or the addition of new files

```
72361c8-dirty
```

### Details

Just like `git status` will show when a submodule is "clean" or "dirty" when using [Git Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), I  really want to see my short commit hash with the word `-dirty` after it if `git status` is dirty! I'm using this inside my build system as a version number in my software, so I can easily see *exactly* which software version I'm running at any moment!

So, I combined this answer (`git rev-parse --short HEAD`) [by @Jakub Narębski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/949391/4561887), and this answer: (`test -n "$(git status --porcelain)"`) [by @benzado on their answer to "Checking for a dirty index or untracked files with Git"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5737794/4561887), I was able to come up with my "1-line" solution above.

The `&&` part only runs if the return code to the previous command (`git status --porcelain`) is `0`, meaning "success" (clean in this case), and the `||` part only runs if the return code of the previous command (`git status --porcelain`) is any other error code, meaning "error" (dirty in this case).

### Going further

See my [bash/git_get_short_hash.sh](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/bash/git_get_short_hash.sh) file in my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/tree/master) repo.

Wrap it in a `git_get_short_hash` Bash function:

```bash
# From my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76856090/4561887
# Get a short commit hash, and see whether `git status` is clean or dirty.
# Example outputs:
# 1. Not in a git repo: `(not a git repo)`
# 2. In a repo which has a "dirty" `git status`: `72361c8-dirty`
#   - Note that "dirty" means there are pending uncommitted changes.
# 3. In a repo which has a "clean" `git status`: `72361c8`
git_get_short_hash() {
    # See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16925062/4561887
    is_git_repo="$(git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree 2>/dev/null)"

    if [ "$is_git_repo" != "true" ]; then
        echo "(not a git repo)"
        return $RETURN_CODE_SUCCESS
    fi

    # See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76856090/4561887
    test -z "$(git status --porcelain)" \
        && echo "$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)" \
        || echo "$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)-dirty"
}
```

Even better, here's a whole program that you can run or source:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# This file is part of eRCaGuy_hello_world: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world

RETURN_CODE_SUCCESS=0
RETURN_CODE_ERROR=1

# From my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76856090/4561887
# Get a short commit hash, and see whether `git status` is clean or dirty.
# Example outputs:
# 1. Not in a git repo: `(not a git repo)`
# 2. In a repo which has a "dirty" `git status`: `72361c8-dirty`
#   - Note that "dirty" means there are pending uncommitted changes.
# 3. In a repo which has a "clean" `git status`: `72361c8`
git_get_short_hash() {
    # See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16925062/4561887
    is_git_repo="$(git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree 2>/dev/null)"

    if [ "$is_git_repo" != "true" ]; then
        echo "(not a git repo)"
        return $RETURN_CODE_SUCCESS
    fi

    # See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76856090/4561887
    test -z "$(git status --porcelain)" \
        && echo "$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)" \
        || echo "$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)-dirty"
}

main() {
    git_get_short_hash
}

# Determine if the script is being sourced or executed (run).
# See:
# 1. "eRCaGuy_hello_world/bash/if__name__==__main___check_if_sourced_or_executed_best.sh"
# 1. My answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70662116/4561887
if [ "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" = "$0" ]; then
    # This script is being run.
    __name__="__main__"
else
    # This script is being sourced.
    __name__="__source__"
fi

# Only run `main` if this script is being **run**, NOT sourced (imported).
# - See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70662116/4561887
if [ "$__name__" = "__main__" ]; then
    main "$@"
fi
```

Sample run command and output when running it:

```bash
eRCaGuy_hello_world$ bash/git_get_short_hash.sh
fddb4ef-dirty
```

Sample run and output by sourcing it (see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62626515/4561887) if you don't know what that means) and then running `main` or `git_get_short_hash` directly:

```bash
eRCaGuy_hello_world$ . bash/git_get_short_hash.sh
eRCaGuy_hello_world$ main
fddb4ef-dirty
eRCaGuy_hello_world$ git_get_short_hash
fddb4ef-dirty
```

**For a Python version of the above program**, see my file here: [**python/git_get_short_hash.py**](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/python/git_get_short_hash.py) in my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/tree/master) repo.

Example usage:

- Use this function in another program of yours like this, for instance.
- First, copy the `git_get_short_hash.py` script into another git project of yours.
- Then, use it like this (assuming `mylogfile` exists):

```py
import git_get_short_hash
import textwrap

# Alias the function to a shorter name
git_get_short_hash = git_get_short_hash.git_get_short_hash3

git_short_hash = git_get_short_hash()
program_info_str = textwrap.dedent(f"""\
    My other program details here...
    Program version: {git_short_hash}
""")
print(program_info_str)
mylogfile.write(program_info_str)
```

### See also

1. My answer here: [Shell script to programmatically interpret the output of `git status`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73284206/4561887)

Comment: Nice use of the `git status --porcelain` [I described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6978402/6309). Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another direct-access implementation:

```bash
head="$(cat ".git/HEAD")"
while [ "$head" != "${head#ref: }" ]; do
  head="$(cat ".git/${head#ref: }")"
done
```

This also works over http which is useful for local package archives (I know: for public web sites it's not recommended to make the .git directory accessable):

```bash
head="$(curl -s "$baseurl/.git/HEAD")"
while [ "$head" != "${head#ref: }" ]; do
  head="$(curl -s "$baseurl/.git/${head#ref: }")"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of doing it with :)

```
git log | grep -o '\w\{8,\}' | head -n 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
echo "printing last commit id# for current branch:";

git reflog
```

[image: Image to show actul results]

Comment: Good to know, although not the answer specific to this exact question

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the newest commit on the `origin/main` branch so I use

```bash
git ls-remote origin | grep main$ | cut -f 1
```