# Undoing a 'git push'

Tags: git, git-push

Here's what I did on my *supposed-to-be-stable* branch...

```bash
% git rebase master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Fast-forwarded alpha-0.3.0 to master.
% git status
# On branch alpha-0.3.0
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/alpha-0.3.0' by 53 commits.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
% git push
Fetching remote heads...
  refs/
  refs/heads/
  refs/tags/
  refs/remotes/
'refs/heads/master': up-to-date
updating 'refs/heads/alpha-0.3.0'
  from cc4b63bebb6e6dd04407f8788938244b78c50285
  to   83c9191dea88d146400853af5eb7555f252001b0
    done
'refs/heads/unstable': up-to-date
Updating remote server info
```

That was all a mistake as I later realized. I'd like to undo this entire process, and revert the alpha-0.3.0 branch back to what it was.

What should I do?

Comment: this stackoverflow post perhaps?

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134882/undoing-a-git-rebase

Comment: It's not really the same situation, undoing a rebase is a local repository scenario, undoing a git push involves a remote repository and can be more tricky depending on the access you have.

Comment: Steen - you're right - I probably should have I suppose.  I figured that the blessed repository that all pull from is more of an admin task and so belongs here, where general client-side git is a stackoverflow question.

Comment: Quick clarification - I'm guessing if you refer to a git commit by a *partial* hash value, git will assume you're talking about the commit whose hash begins with that string?

Answer (score 1293, accepted):

You need to make sure that no other users of this repository are fetching the incorrect changes or trying to build on top of the commits that you want removed because you are about to rewind history.

Then you need to 'force' push the old reference.

```
git push -f origin last_known_good_commit:branch_name
```

or in your case

```
git push -f origin cc4b63bebb6:alpha-0.3.0
```

You may have `receive.denyNonFastForwards` set on the remote repository. If this is the case, then you will get an error which includes the phrase `[remote rejected]`.

In this scenario, you will have to delete and recreate the branch.

```
git push origin :alpha-0.3.0
git push origin cc4b63bebb6:refs/heads/alpha-0.3.0
```

If this doesn't work - perhaps because you have `receive.denyDeletes` set, then you have to have direct access to the repository. In the remote repository, you then have to do something like the following plumbing command.

```
git update-ref refs/heads/alpha-0.3.0 cc4b63bebb6 83c9191dea8
```

Comment: A perfect and well explained response - thank you very much.

For anyone else who stumbles accross this, for academic reasons I tried both of the first 2 approaches, and both worked - obviously if the first one works, it's the cleanest approach.

If I chould UP you 10 times Charles, I would. :)

Comment: For quick-reference, the first line here is `git push -f origin last_known_good_commit:branch_name`

Comment: git push -f origin cc4b63bebb6:alpha-0.3.0 => this one helped me, Note alpha-0.3.0 is the branch name and cc4b63bebb6 is the commit id we wish to revert back to. so, after carrying out this command we wil be in cc4b63bebb6 commit id.

Comment: This solution is highly dangerous if you are working in a shared repo. As a best practice, all commits pushed to a remote repo that is shared should be considered 'immutable'. Use 'git revert' instead: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#fixing-mistakes

Comment: jww - compared to everything else, git is the most feature-rich and efficient source control tool available. Every team uses it differently. It's worth spending a weekend playing around with a fresh repository and going through all the common scenarios. Once you've spent some time working with it, development is a lot less stressful.

Comment: What if others have fetched?

Comment: this forget to mention that, you loose any local work in the process. I wrongfully had pushed to the wrong branch some changes did this git push -f and loose my previous local changes :p  Thanks you IntelliJ for the Local History feature saved my ass :p

Comment: Not worked with **LFS**: after trivial push like `git push -f origin good_commit:master` it returns an error message, *"Locking support detected on remote 'origin'. Consider enabling it with: `$ git config 'lfs.github.com/authority/project.git/info/lfs.locksverify'; true`"*... After the suggested `git config` worked fine (!), important to do `git config ... false` after all, to back to normal LDF activity.

Comment: WHAT A SAVE!!! I had code that hadn't been committed in one repository and wanted to push changes I made in another, but GitHub Desktop was in the wrong repository and I pushed the not ready changes instead.

Comment: After executing the `git push -f`, remember to do also a `git reset --hard <last_known_good_commit_ID>` to "undo" changes in your local repository too.

Answer (score 223):

I believe that you can also do this:

```
git checkout alpha-0.3.0
git reset --hard cc4b63bebb6
git push origin +alpha-0.3.0
```

This is very similar to the last method, except you don't have to muck around in the remote repo.

Comment: This worked for me as well, but it's worth noting that this will "re-write" history on the remote. This may be what you want, but it may not be!

Comment: +1 for this answer that really helped me out.  I also wanted to add (and make things clear) that the commit ID (which comes after the "`--hard`" parameter) should be the ID of whatever commit you want to reset your branch to.

Comment: how come when I do `git pull`, I get something like: `fe88549..50a8083  master     -> origin/master
Already up-to-date.`

Comment: Rewrote history nicely... anyone who could have pulled the changes, I just made sure they did a `git reset --hard [commit_id]` so we didn't mess with the space-time continuum.

Comment: What is the + for in "git push origin +alpha-0.3.0"?

Comment: Hi, I do only `git push -f origin 99157a1b1b27820dfba48c5e9d3c4f075670670c:master ` as Charles recipe,  and **nothing ocurr**... How to use your recipe? It is the *simplest case*: delete the last commit from master.

Comment: This rewrites history and I believe you'll need to force your push in this case. eg(git push -f .....)

Comment: @jpierson `+` forces the push to take place, similarly to `-f` (but slightly different: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25937833/1757149). Without it, if you try `git push origin alpha-0.3.0` the push will fail: `Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind`.

Answer (score 134):

`git revert` is less dangerous than some of the approaches suggested here:

```
prompt> git revert 35f6af6f77f116ef922e3d75bc80a4a466f92650
[master 71738a9] Revert "Issue #482 - Fixed bug."
 4 files changed, 30 insertions(+), 42 deletions(-)
prompt> git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
prompt>
```

Replace 35f6af6f77f116ef922e3d75bc80a4a466f92650 with your own commit.

Comment: How do I come up with the 35f6af6f77f116ef922e3d75bc80a4a466f92650 ID? This answer would be better if you could explain that.

Comment: @Volomike (and Googling devs of the future), this question describes many ways of obtaining it: [version control and hash question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949314/how-to-retrieve-the-hash-for-the-current-commit-in-git)

Comment: This is the right answer, because with "git reset" you should not be able to push (Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart) or you need to force the pull which is not really clean.

Comment: This was working for me. However, be careful as revert will revert all changes in your local files.

Comment: I opted for this approach multiple times but also I use git rebase -i <id-before-last-good-commit> to do an interactive rebase and clean up history as suggested here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git.

Comment: @Volomike just do git log and you will find it

Comment: For beginners: [git revert](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) only reverts the ONE commit you mention. It does NOT restore  your commit back to exactly match the commit mentioned.  Use `git restore` for that.

Answer (score 55):

A way to do it without losing the changes you wanted:

```
git reset cc4b63b 
git stash
git push -f origin alpha-0.3.0
git stash pop
```

Then you can choose the files you meant to push

Answer (score 39):

```
git push origin +7f6d03:master
```

This will revert your repo to mentioned commit number

Comment: Remember, that won't reset your local files.

Comment: This is what I needed, as I wanted to simply undo a push without losing my local changes.

Comment: Year, good to me.

Answer (score 39):

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
git push origin -f
```

This will remove the last commit from your local device as well as Github

Comment: Just to be clear, git reset --hard is a DANGEROUS command. Any previously pending changes to the Staging Index and the Working Directory gets reset to match the state of the Commit Tree. This means any pending work that was hanging out in the Staging Index and Working Directory will be lost.

Answer (score 37):

The accepted solution (from @charles bailey) is highly dangerous if you are working in a shared repo.

As a best practice, all commits pushed to a remote repo that is shared should be considered 'immutable'.
Use 'git revert' instead: 
http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#fixing-mistakes

https://git-scm.com/book/be/v2/Git-Basics-Undoing-Things

Comment: What, exactly, are the instructions you are prescribing? You only seem to have old links.

Answer (score 25):

Another way to do this:

1. create another branch
2. checkout the previous commit on that branch using "git checkout"
3. push the new branch.
4. delete the old branch & push the delete (use `git push origin --delete <branch_name>`)
5. rename the new branch into the old branch
6. push again.

Comment: This one looks like a real solution when you have already wrong commits in repo

Answer (score 19):

***Scenario 1***: If you want to undo the last commit say 8123b7e04b3, below is the command(this worked for me):

```
git push origin +8123b7e04b3^:<branch_name>
```

Output looks like below:

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://testlocation/code.git
 + 8123b7e...92bc500 8123b7e04b3^ -> master (forced update)
```

Note: To update the change to your local code (to remove the commit locally as well) :

```
$ git reset --hard origin/<branchName>
Message displayed is :    HEAD is now at 8a3902a comments_entered_for_commit
```

**Additional info:**
***Scenario 2***: In some situation, you may want to revert back what you just undo'ed (basically undo the undo) through the previous command, then use the below command:

```
git reset --hard 8123b7e04b3
git push
```

Output:

```
HEAD is now at cc6206c Comment_that_was_entered_for_commit
```

More info here: https://github.com/blog/2019-how-to-undo-almost-anything-with-git

Comment: Scenario 1 should the accepted answer since the question did not specify which commit to delete. The accepted answer only deletes the *last* commit. This answer deletes *any* commit.

Answer (score 18):

Undo multiple commits
`git reset --hard 0ad5a7a6` (Just provide commit SHA1 hash)

Undo last commit

`git reset --hard HEAD~1` (changes to last commit will be removed )  `git reset --soft HEAD~1` (changes to last commit will be available as uncommited local modifications)

Answer (score 7):

you can use the command reset

```
git reset --soft HEAD^1
```

then:

```
git reset <files>
git commit --amend
```

and

```
git push -f
```

Answer (score 1):

To revert the push

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
git push -f
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```

now your local will be ahead to remote

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

**or alternative way**

1. To reset the push: `git reset --soft HEAD^1`
2. Will appear modify file so reset them: `git reset <files>`
3. git commit --amend
4. git push -f

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers are good and correct, however what if you need to undo the `push` but:

1. You want to keep the commits locally or you want to keep uncommitted changes
2. You don't know how many commits you just pushed

Use this command to revert the change to the ref:

```
git push -f origin refs/remotes/origin/<branch>@{1}:<branch>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I just copy the last commit id(af12de...) which I wanted to revert. Then executes this command
`git revert af12de...`. Then push my changes to the `master`. This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to undo a certain push, you can also do this interactively via

```
git rebase -i HEAD~n
```

where `n` should denote how many commits into the past you want to go, e.g.

```
git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

Now you can interactively go to the commit in the terminal you want to drop (remove) and write "drop" (though in the terminal that opens up, this is also explained very well).

When you are done with the rebase, do not forget to forcably push the changes, i.e.

```
git push origin branch_name --force
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this answer is apparently a duplicate of the question [How can I remove a commit on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448919/how-can-i-remove-a-commit-on-github), and answers cannot be added there because it is marked as duplicate, the correct not-yet-posted answer for that question is this:

**You need to contact support.** GitHub's help docs say (emphasis mine):

> commits may still be accessible in any clones or forks of your repository, directly via their SHA-1 hashes in cached views on GitHub, and through any pull requests that reference them. You cannot remove sensitive data from other users' clones of your repository, but you can **permanently remove** cached views and references to the sensitive data in pull requests on GitHub **by contacting us** through the [GitHub Support portal](https://support.github.com).

Until their support removes it manually, you can always still view the commit ID, and in pull requests it will permanently be shown, even if you used `git reset`, `git gc`, `push -f`, etc. as other answers suggest.

For your own repository, deleting the whole repository seems to be the only thing you can do by yourself to make GitHub delete a commit ID. (Note that they will still keep a copy if the commit was referenced elsewhere.)

You should consider leaked secret tokens public no matter how short-lived it was on the website (there are automatic scanners that pick these up), but if you need to additionally wait for a support team to get around to deleting something like the wrong committer name in a pull request, others will definitely have seen it and you can consider your alter ego burned...

Answer (score -2):

If you want to ignore the last commit that you have just pushed in the remote branch: this will not remove the commit but just ignoring it by moving the `git pointer` to the commit one earlier, refered by `HEAD^` or `HEAD^1`

```
git push origin +HEAD^:branch
```

But if you have already pushed this commit, and others have pulled the branch. In this case, rewriting your branch's history is undesirable and you should instead revert this `commit`:

```
git revert <SHA-1>
git push origin branch
```

Comment: The question is about "push" then it concern the Remote branch.
No to move the HEAD about one commit which mean ignore the last commit pushed  just do this:   git push origin +HEAD^:your_branch