# Rewinding remote git branch

Tags: git, version-control

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How do I push amended commit to the remote git repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253055/how-do-i-push-amended-commit-to-the-remote-git-repo)
>   [Undoing a git push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270514/undoing-a-git-push)

Hi,

I've deleted some commits from my master branch by using

```
git reset --hard SHA_VALUE
```

I have, however a remote version of the repository on github, and whenever I `git push` things, I get an error message, that I should merge the changes contained in the remote repository (which I do not want to).

So my question is, what is the remote equivalent to the `git reset` command?

thx

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253055 or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270514

Comment: Thanks! git push origin +master:master did it for me

Comment: In that case I'm voting to close as a duplicate of "pushing an amended commit" as it has the same solution and pitfalls as what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 6):

You can use "git push" with  "force" option

```
git push -f
```

via manpages:

> ```
>    -f, --force
>        Usually, the command refuses to update a remote ref that is not an ancestor of the local ref 
>        used to overwrite it. This flag disables the check. This can cause the remote repository to 
>        lose commits; use it with care.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do a "git rebase". Check this [article](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~cduan/technical/git/git-5.shtml) on rebasing and read the section titled "Common Rebasing Use Practices".