# Can I undo the last git push?

Tags: git

A team member accidentally pushed half a gig of unwanted zips to the remote repo last night when they were in a rush. Yes... oops.

Nobody has pulled or committed since.

Ideally I want to just 'undo' what happened.

I have looked at filter-branch and was thinking of trying something like

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f *.zip' HEAD
```

but that would be local, and I can't figure out how to do it direct on the remote repo.

Is there a simpler way to undo what happened? If she amends her last commit and pushes again will that undo the push - ie actually remove those files from the history?

Obviously if she deletes them, commits and pushes again then that still leaves the content in the repo, which is no good.

Comment: There are similar questions up perhaps they could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270514/undoing-a-git-push

Answer (score 55):

Thanks Don, I'd seen that but somehow hadn't realised it fixed my problem, because I only have one branch.

I did:

```
git push -f origin 5910117a8fc2c71334251465b54d6d9daeb28d1c:master
```

And it's all back to how it was.

Comment: that works fine. you might like to take a moment to think about whether letting anyone with access to the repo being able to do that is good or not :) going to the remote repo directly and using git reset to move its master branch is another alternative that can usually bypass any permissions checks implemented in hooks.

Comment: You might want to add:
git reset --hard 5910117a8fc2c71334251465b54d6d9daeb28d1c

That will make sure your local copy is also reverted back to that specific revision (otherwise, it will seem like your local repo differs from the remote).

Comment: clarification: the sha hash should be the hash of the last GOOD commit - not your bad commit push

Comment: just for the sake of completeness of this answer, you should specify that, in order to get the last commit hash, one have to do `git log`. Pretty handy answer, though.

Answer (score 7):

I think

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
git push -f
```

should to the trick: It resets your local checkout to the previous commit (assuming the last one is the one you want to drop) and force pushes it to the remote repository.