# Wiping a remote branch history without a good initial commit

Tags: git

I have two local repos: `a-public-project` and `top-secret`, after making numerous commits to both local repos I then created a new empty repo on GitHub which will be the remote for `a-public-project`, however I accidentally pushed `top-secret` instead:

```
cd C:/Git/top-secret
git remote add github https://github.com/me/a-public-project.git
git push -u github master
```

In panic mode, I searched online and found these results:

- [Undoing a 'git push'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270514/undoing-a-git-push)
- [Git: permanently remove few commits from remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293531/git-permanently-remove-few-commits-from-remote-)
- [Is there a way to rollback my last push to Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655052/is-there-a-way-to-rollback-my-last-push-to-git)
- http://christoph.ruegg.name/blog/git-howto-revert-a-commit-already-pushed-to-a-remote-reposit.htmlbranch

Unfortunately, all of these involve resetting my local branch and doing `git push --force`: this assumes there's a good intentional commit that I can rollback to. In this case, I don't  - the entire repo history is bad and the *remote* repo needs its history deleted (but my local repo history untouched, obviously).

Fortunately, in this particular instance I was able to delete the repo using the GitHub website and then push the correct local repo, but what should I do if this happens again with a repo I don't control?

Answer (score 2):

one quick way to recover would be to delete the master branch from the remote

```
git push github :master
```

or you could quickly hop over to `a-public-project` and force push that to overwrite

```
cd C:/Git/a-public-project
git remote add github https://github.com/me/a-public-project.git
git push -u github master --force
```

Comment: I see the significance of the colon here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303687/why-git-use-the-colon-branch-to-delete-remote-branch