# git how to disable push

Tags: git, push

I am using git and I am doing my development work, which I don't want to push, even by mistake. Is there a method to disable push in certain local repository. One method is to rename the branch, another is to [undo push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270514/undoing-a-git-push) if one does it by mistake, but I hope there should be a more direct method.

Comment: Please don't delete this as duplicate, the title wording is much easier to find with Google than the "original" question.

Answer (score 404, accepted):

The following command will let pulls work, but pushes will try to use the URL `no_push` and fail:

```
git remote set-url --push origin no_push
```

Comment: Thanks. How to disable 'push of only a certain branch'?

Comment: @user984260: I guess you could set the remote for just that branch: `git config branch.<branch-name>.remote no_push`. But if the branch is a local development branch, with its own name, is it really a problem? It won't be pushed by default (`git push` with no arguments by default pushes only branches which exist both locally and on the remote) and even if you do push it, you're just creating a new branch on the remote which you can promptly delete.

Comment: Whatever you do, use `git config -l` to verify/get a better understanding. (If it isn't there, it didn't happen ;-) ). Even better structured, use `cat .git/config`

Comment: wouldn't that prevent push on all branches?

Comment: Thanx! If you have an upstream repo in addition to origin then you can do the following to make sure you can't push to upstream: `git remote set-url --push upstream no_push`. Check the effect with `git remote -v` before and after the change.

Comment: How do I undo this change now?? Github isn't working properly and I cannot merge my branch, I can do it locally but now I can't push that...

Comment: @OZZIE you can use the same `git set-url` command to allow pushes again - it'll be something like `git set-url --push origin git@github.com:my-user/my-repo.git`. If you issue a `git config --list` it's likely that the original setting is there as `remote.origin.url=<the thing you want>`

Answer (score 7):

Depending on the remote, you may be able to reset its URL to use the read-only Git protocol instead of SSH or HTTPS. E.g., for a project on GitHub, do

```
git remote set-url <remote> git://github.com/Team/Project.git
```

where `<remote>` is commonly `origin`. `git remote -v` will give you a list of remotes; those that start with `https` or have the form `<user>@<host>:<path>` usually allow pushing.

Comment: Didn't work for me! This prevents pulls as well :(

Comment: @YassineElBadaoui you probably need to add `--push` after `set-url` to just modify for pushing.  But [this more recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10260389/328817) makes the intent clearer when you come back to this in future, I think.