# How to limit push to particular remote repository?

Tags: git, github

I have to pull request, but push upstream repository.

How to limit push to particular remote repository?

my hope is limit push to my upstream repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your remote repo from which you are pulling the pull request is named "`pr`" (for example, but see what `git remote -v` returns), you can do as described in "[git how to disable push](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10260389/6309)":

```
git remote set-url --push pr no_push
```

That would leave the remote "`origin`" (which should be your upstream repo) untouched, and you would be able to push only to `origin`.