# In Netbeans, is there a way to use Git read-only?

Tags: git, netbeans

Using Netbeans 8.1 in Windows and Git on Linux CLI.

I have a Netbeans project, with source files residing on a mapped SMB share from a linux machine. Netbeans' version of the repository is stored local to this machine, and I do not commit from Netbeans. All of my commits are made via Git on the remote machine.

Is it possible to setup Netbeans to use the remote repository read-only, and update its history when the remote git commits to the repo?

Comment: I suppose another way to look at it is this: If someone wanted to manage a Git repo with one Git server, such as Git for Windows, but read-only use the repo with Netbeans. That the repo is technically stored on another machine/OS is not particularly important.

Answer (score 2):

This would not be specific to Netbeans, but you can [configure your local repo to prevent pushing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10260389/6309):

```
git remote set-url --push origin no_push
```

As for the update, unless you setup some kind of [webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) on the remote repo side (which a simple repo does not have, contrary to a Git repo hosting service like GitHub), you would need to fetch at regular interval.

If you don't need to be in sync at all time, you can simply [pull and rebase before pushing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309).

```
git config pull.rebase true
git config rebase.autoStash true
```

Again, not specifc to NetBeans, but Netbeans will take into account those local Git repo settings.

> If someone wanted to manage a Git repo with one Git server, such as Git for Windows, but read-only use the repo with Netbeans.

One simple answer: [take an archive of your repo](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) and unzip it somewhere for NetBeans to use: this is no longer a Git repo, and NetBeans does not risk to add any commit to it.

Comment: Thank you. The repo is hosted on GitHub, so commits do eventually make it into Netbeans when I push from the other local, but I commit much more frequently than I push.

Comment: Thank you... but that still seems to be another version of the same problem: the repo the IDE is trying to maintain stays out of date vs the actual repo for the files it is editing. Currently, things catch up only when I push to origin. In the meantime, code-highlighting of differences show the diffs versus the last push, rather than the last commit.