# roll back remote repo after pushing

Tags: git, git-push

Ive made a bit of a mess of my repo.

Ive made some changes & pushed them up to the repo & now id like to undo that.  (i merged things all wrong)

On my local machine I have done that with the following command:

```
git reset --hard 72a535b
```

Which seems to have done the trick.  Then i implemented the changes correctly, committed them & attempted to push.

Of course thats failed with error

> denying non-fast0forward refs/heads/master  (you should pull first)

which i don't think i want to do, as then ill lose my changes and be back to the 1st set of broken mods.

how can i sort this horrible mess out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undoing a git push](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270514/undoing-a-git-push)

Comment: Ive found a setting on the remote repos control panel (its beanstalk) to allow force push.  i did that & it went through without error.  There is nothing in the activity feed on beanstalk but the files seem right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming no-one has pulled your "bad" changes yet, force the push:

```
git push -f
```

The server rejects the normal push, because it would cause the serverside repo to lose changes (your mess). In this case, this seems to be what you want, so go ahead and force it. Just be aware that forcing a push is in general a dangerous thing to do, because you can lose history.

It can get messy if other users has already pulled your changes, because then they will have to resolve the conflicts in a meaningful way before they can push. So if you have any collaborators on the project, be sure to check if they have already got your copy of the code, and if they do, warn them about what you are about to do and make sure they pull the right version as soon as it is available.

Comment: One collaborator has pulled the changes.  what do they need to do  to resolve it on their machine?

Comment: also.  Iv'e tried -f - I still goet remote rejected master -> master (non-fast-forward)

Comment: try `git push origin +master`. The other developer has to fetch your new changes and then either rebase his changes on top of them or reset his local branch to the new tip commit.

Comment: @knittl maybe you meant `git push -f origin +master`?

Comment: @CharlesB: No, I meant `git push origin +master`. `+` in front of a refspec means "force"

Comment: There was a setting on the remote server to allow non fast forward.  Ticking this and trying force worked.  Then on the other machine we did a revert to that same commit & then pulled.  both dev machines & the remote are now all in sync.  phew.  thanks all for helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your best and safe option is

```
 git revert
```

OK, it create and extra commit and your bad commit stays for life. Buy why care. As long as top of branch is clean why hide past mistakes.

Comment: + never try to rewrite history unless you are sure about possible side effects.

Comment: i don't care.  can you expand a bit more on how to use it in this situation?

Comment: also, its 3 commits, how do i undo each one? git revert is just doing the last one

Comment: please use "git revert commit-id". Commits should be reverted in First in Last Out order. As fast non fast forward push you can use "git push --force" and your server must be configured to accept force push.

Comment: You can pass a range commit to revert and then apply rebase -i squashing revert commits to one, then push one commit reverting whole range.

Comment: none of these will keep the changes i have written since rolling back locally right?

Comment: also, now that i have done the reset --hard - are these sugestions sill valid?

Comment: once you roll back changes and commit it in local clone your work tree will not have those changes. After you push and other pull it in their work tree changes will disappear. I still request you NOT to do force push. Let bad history be there and just do revert

Comment: forvaidya, at this point just getting my local, the remote and the other local the same is all i care about.  but don't worry.  force push doesn't work anyway.