# Retrieving orphaned commit object after push --force

Tags: git

Doing `push --force` is always kinda risky and here is an example of how it could produce some problems like loosing revisions remotely.

Suppose, there is some person **Bob** that has updated remote `master` branch from `B` to `C`. And there is another person **Mike** that doesn't fetch this update yet and `HEAD` of his `master` is  still `B`. Then `Mike` do `push --force` and suddenly roll back remote `master` to `B` again:

```
mike@laptop $> git push --force origin
Counting objects: 19, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
Writing objects: 100% (12/12), 2.27 KiB, done.
Total 12 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: => Syncing... [OK]
To git@gitserver.com:path/to/project.git
   C..B  master -> master (forced update)
```

In other words, before **Mike** did that, remote master was like `A---B---C` and he changed it to `A---B`.

As you can see, `C` revision here is remote only - it exists on git-server and on the **Bob**'s laptop, because he pushed it to the remote `master`. It means that there is no such local ref `C` on the **Mike**'s laptop.

**Question 1**: how can **Mike** set remote `master` back to `C`?

**Mike** has tried to solve that problem with `push --force` again like the [answer for similar question offers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1270514), but it doesn't work because there is no suck local ref:

```
mike@laptop $> git push --force origin C:master
error: src refspec C does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitserver.com:path/to/project.git'
```

**Question 2**: how can **Mike** fetch `C` revision from the git server? And if he can't do that - why git designed like that? Is it about safety in some rare cases? What problems it exactly prevents?

Usually `fetch` retrieves branches and tags only, but `C` doesn't belong to any branch (which means that there is no any remote branch that `C` is parent commit or `HEAD` of).

PS: let's assume that **Mike** has no ssh access to git server, it means that there is no way to call git from the server side.

PPS: **Mike** doesn't want **Bob** to know about that accident, so answer "Make **Bob** to push this commit again" is not what this question is about.

Comment: Why does `git fetch` not satisfy your use case, and what do you mean that the commit "doesn't belong to any branch"?

Comment: If we can assume the git server is Github, Mike could use the API to [create a new branch at the orphaned commit](http://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/#create-a-reference), then fetch the no longer orphaned commit and repair.

Comment: Note that while push-to repos are usually bare, and thus have the reflog disabled, nothing prevents you from enabling it by setting `core.logAllRefUpdates` to `true` in them, and then all "drastic" branch movements will be logged and available via the reflog (in the server repo only, I suppose -- one can't access the reflog remotely, AIUI).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Anyone who has commit `C` locally can use `git branch some-name C` to give `C` a name, then `git push origin some-name:master` to (try to) append `C` back to master on origin.

Anyone who doesn't have `C` can't recover `C` at all (even if it's in origin's object store).

**Mike** *cannot* fix the problem except using a repo that contains commit `C` (possibly the shared one, possibly **Bob**'s, possibly some other repo that was cloned when `C` was on master).

You can't push commits you don't have locally. The local half of `git-push` has to be able to walk history to figure out what objects to upload, and it can't do that if it doesn't have that history available.

You can't fetch commits that aren't reachable from refs, because literally every git security layer out there does security on a ref-by-ref basis, not an object-by-object basis, and because there's no real reason to reference loose objects remotely. Git's remoting layer is entirely built around copying refs around.

But you can fetch arbitrary commits' contents using git-archive, if the server has that feature turned on. Most don't, and even if yours does, it's not enough information to reconstruct the commit object.

(c) irc://freenode/#git, ojacobson

Answer (score 16):

If you are using GitHub, you can follow the steps in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34618633/2461232) to create a branch on commit `C` after it has been orphaned.

Comment: Nope, this question is not related to github, thus there is no such tag and any mention either. Thank you for the link anyway

Comment: Bingo! Great to have a solution for GitHub, even if OP did not mention it specifically.

Comment: For Gitlab, a similar method works using a tag instead of a branch (described in the comments of the linked answer).

Comment: THANK YOU!! THIS IS A LIFE-SAVER! applicable in gitlab too :)

Answer (score 4):

These git commands solves the issue. **Only works if you have the full hash.**

```
# Fetch the remote commit and create a reference for it
git fetch origin C:refs/remotes/origin/foo-commit

# Checkout the remote branch we just created
git checkout foo-commit

# Force push foo-commit branch to master
git push -f origin master
```

A nice extra is that it does not touch the local master branch.

Answer (score 3):

Without access to the server, this is ... very hard, at best.  (I say "hard at best" as it might be possible to write a program that uploads no pack, then sends a rev update that mentions `C` by number.  I don't know if this would work at all; it might.)

In general, though, the server will have acquired revision `C` from some client (most push servers are `--bare` which means no work was actually performed on the server).  That *client* has the missing commit and it's very easy to recover the commit there (find in reflog, add a new branch or tag, push).

If you have ssh access to the server, log in and use `git fsck` to find the dropped commit (or if you have the abbreviated SHA-1 just use that), then use `git branch` or `git tag` to create a reference to it.

Edit, per question edit: it's actually possible that Mike *does* have commit *`C`*.  He can try, e.g., `git rev-parse C` to see if he has it.  But the `git push --force origin C:master` failure already tells us that he does not have it.  Why can't he get it?  Because when he connects to the server, he says (in effect) "here are my branch heads, what are yours?" and the server says (in effect) "oh, mine are these, would you like some of these?".  That's all that's in the protocol—the client can't go ask for specific commits by ID, at least, not through these interfaces.  Some web server access methods *do* allow you to send over raw SHA-1 values and ask for the corresponding object(s); you'd have to find out if the server is running any such service.

As for "Mike doesn't want Bob to know about that accident" ... well, sometimes you just have to confess. :-)

Comment: Your intuition about that program that might work is correct!  I wrote [a script](https://github.com/cryslith/git-recover-commit) which does exactly what you described (upload no pack, update ref) and it works fine :)