# How can I pull down a commit from Github (Enterprise) that I don't have locally?

Tags: git, github

I accidentally did a `push --force` on the wrong repo (too many termminals open), effectively resetting the master branch back to an earlier commit.

Looking at my build system I can see that the commit used to point to XYZ, however I don't have that commit locally as I hadn't done a pull or fetch recently. The repo is in Github, and I can navigate in Github to view the commit, so I know it is there.

How can I pull down the commit so I can reset `master` back to the right commit without having to bother the dev who pushed that change?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can create a branch from an orphaned commit in the Github GUI by doing the following:

1. Browse to https://github.com/yourOrg/yourRepo/tree/**commitHash**
2. Click on the branch dropdown
3. Type in the new branch name and hit Enter

Now that you have a branch, you can use your Git client to check it out as normal.

[image: Github create branch drop down]

### Notes

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18910545) was helpful as I researched this. It basically states that you are stuck unless you have a local repository containing the orphaned commits. My approach allows you to add a branch so the commit is no longer orphaned.

Comment: I wrote [a script](https://github.com/cryslith/git-recover-commit) which does the same thing using the pure Git protocol, without using GitHub's UI.

Comment: For Gitlab, a similar method works: if you can find the commit page, ex: https://gitlab.kitware.com/account/project/commit/e431ddca then click `Option` > `Tag` and choose a tag name. Then you can `git fetch --tags` and `git checkout chosen-tag-name`.

Comment: @LilyChung You should definitely post you script as an answer to give it more visibility. You saved my day!

Comment: definitely a life saver - somehow 2 merged PRs disappeared
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is XYZ is reachable by some branch you can simply fetch. If not, please follow @weste's instructions to get it pointed to by a branch and then fetch:

```
git fetch
git checkout master
git reset --hard XYZ
git push -f origin master
```

Comment: I don't have the commit locally and it isn't reachable by any branch.

Comment: please follow @weste's instructions to get it pointed to by a branch and then fetch

Answer (score 0):

I understand currently you don't have the commit locally; nevertheless you can get it, without modifying your workspace, simply like this:

```
git fetch
```

After that, if ever you have current modification, or something like that, you can stash them temporary:

```
git stash save "My work to be completed later"
```

Then you can move back to your master branch:

```
git checkout -f master
```

Then, force to move the HEAD to the orphan commit you want:

```
git reset --hard XYZ
```

As alternative, in case, you prefer destroying and recreating your master branch, you can "move" to another branch, destroy the master branch and recreate it:

```
git checkout -b anyOtherBranch
git branch -D master
git checkout -b master XYZ
```

And eventually, push force your new master branch;

```
git push --force origin master
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Bsquare! When I made the bounty I intended to directly award westse's answer which helped me greatly in a tight spot. Unfortunately StackExchange's policy forces me to wait for 24 hours, which is probably why the question showed up for you.