# How can I roll back a Git repository and its remote?

Tags: git, repository

I have a Git repo that I'd like to roll back by about a dozen commits using...

```
git reset --hard d3289a7ab82fd76386d99bdd2c5e6496ecc62529
```

The problem is I've already pushed the commits to the remote.

How can I return everything including the remote to the state it was in at the specified commit?

Comment: Why don't you just `git revert` the commits and push those?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1463340/78845

Comment: You can use git push-f origin as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270514/undoing-a-git-push

Comment: @NikhilTitus: You ***can*** `git push --force`, but you really shouldn't alter others' history. Once you've published commits, you should `revert` them and push the reverts.

Comment: @Ethan, have you had any luck resolving this?

Answer (score 1):

Reset locally, then force the push to Github – your remote and local will be in identical states:

```
git reset --hard d3289a7ab82fd76386d99bdd2c5e6496ecc62529
git push -f
```

Comment: This is not recommended if the commits have been pushed. Other repo users could have fetched and this will break their history.

Comment: Very true, but the OP is asking how the remote can be rolled back while staying in sync with local. If local undergoes a hard reset (as the OP has indicated), the subsequent commits are effectively erased from history. It's fair, then, that those commits are flushed from remote as well. Also, we have no idea what the OP's Github repo is for – it may be for his/her own use alone.

Comment: This can be also disallowed by remote. For example, on github you can't do that, if I'm not mistaken.