# Git revert push to the previous push

Tags: git, version-control, github, revert

I did a mistake that is explained below:

I was on the branch `feature5` which was around 200 commits forward compared to `master`, I created a local branch `documentation` from `feature5`. (I forgot I wasn't on `master`)

Then, I committed and pushed new/updated documents to `origin/documentation` (I thought the `documentation` branch didn't exists on `origin`. (Many projects... Lost my mind)

Then, I realized that I pushed in `documentation` about 200 commits that should not belongs to this branch. How can I revert it?

I took a look to this discussion, but I'm pretty lost in my `documentation` branch, I don't know where I should revert because there are too many commits from `feature5` on it, I would like to revert the entire last push on this branch, is it possible? Or to know what was the last commit before my bad push?

[Undoing a 'git push'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270514/undoing-a-git-push)

Another solution would be to delete the `origin/documentation` and create a new one based on master, because master contains the old `origin/documentation` branch without the bad last push, but I would like to try to keep the `origin/documentation` branch *alive* if possible. And who knows, maybe I'll need to do the same thing in a few days/weeks/months ^_^

I also took a quick look to `git-revert` but I don't see how it could help me so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can fix this by rebasing your `documentation` branch on to master using the `--onto` parameter.

```
git rebase --onto origin/master HEAD~n
```

where "n" is the number of commits you actually care about in the `documentation` branch.

You will then need to use the `-f` flag when you push up your new `documentation` branch.

Comment: THe git rebase rollback `documentation` to the master HEAD, but I lost the last commit in the operation.

Comment: I used `git cherry-pick 4de68af` to apply the commit lost to the `documentation` branch. Now I run `git push -f` and everything is ok. Thanks.