# How to undo a 'git push'

Tags: git, commit, revert

I am a complete neophyte with git  If it is in any way possible for someone to screw something up or not know it, assume that to be the case :-)

I added my changes, did a commit, and issued a 'git push origin' but forgot to append the branch.  So git cheerfully pushed my work into the master.  I tried a 'git revert', but that deleted my changes from my computer.

How do I get my work out of master and back on to my computer, and then revert master back to the way it was before?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undoing a git push](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270514/undoing-a-git-push)

Answer (score 1):

Start on master, and run a git pull so the remote and your local are in sync.

Checkout your feature branch, and run a `git cherry-pick` for the commits that you want.

Checkout master, and run a `git reset --hard <commit-id>` to the commit you wish to go back to.

Then you can do a  `git push --force` on master to update the remote.