# Git Force push syntax, "-f" versus "+branch"

Tags: git

What is the difference between these two git commands when force pushing changes?

`git push -f origin branch` and `git push origin +branch`

Answer (score 75, accepted):

## TL;DR

If you're only pushing one branch, there is no difference.

```
git push -f origin branch
```

and

```
git push origin +branch
```

are exact equivalents. The difference arises when you're pushing *more than one* branch with a single `git push`.

In a nutshell, **the optional `+` gives you finer control than `-f` does**: if you're pushing more than one ref at a time, the `+` allows you to specify which of the pushed refs get force-pushed, whereas `--force` (or `-f`) applies to *all* the refs that are getting pushed.

## More details

### What the `git-push` man page tells you

The most basic form of `git push` that involve one or more refspec(s) is

```
git push <repository> <refspec>...
```

The form that the `<refspec>...` argument must satisfy is described in the `git-push` man page thus:

> `<refspec>...`
>
> ```
> Specify what destination ref to update with what source object. The
> format of a `<refspec>` parameter is an optional plus `+`, followed by
> the source object `<src>`, followed by a colon `:`, followed by the
> destination ref `<dst>`.
> ```

So, just to be clear, the syntax for `<refspec>` is

```
[+]<src>[:<dest>]
```

If `:<dst>` is omitted, the same ref as `<src>` will be updated... unless the `remote.<repository>.push` entry (if any) in your Git config says otherwise.

Further down in the [`git-push` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push), you find

> By having the optional leading `+`, you can tell Git to update the `<dst>`
>   ref even if it is not allowed by default (e.g., it is not a
>   fast-forward.) This does not attempt to merge `<src>` into `<dst>`.

And still further down:

> Note that `--force` applies to all the refs that are pushed, hence
>   using it with `push.default` set to `matching` or with multiple push
>   destinations configured with `remote.*.push` may overwrite refs other
>   than the current branch (including local refs that are strictly behind
>   their remote counterpart). To force a push to only one branch, use a `+`
>   in front of the refspec to push (e.g `git push origin +master` to force
>   a push to the `master` branch).

### Example

Consider a local repo with two branches, `master` and `develop`, which you want to push (with a single `git push` command) to an `origin` remote.

- `git push origin master develop` will push both branches, but neither will get force-pushed.
- `git push origin +master develop` will push both branches, but only `master` will get force-pushed.
- `git push origin master +develop` , conversely, will push both branches, but only `develop` will get force-pushed.
- `git push origin +master +develop` will force-push both branches. It's an exact equivalent to `git push -f origin master develop`.