# How do i delete the last 3 commits?

Tags: git, version-control

**How do i delete the last 3 commits?** there is probably many examples but I think i ma being very specific here with what I want.

So for example I have done a `git add .` and `git commit -m "message"` and a `git push -u origin master` for all these.

I have the following output from all my commits(with 21 being the most recent commit)

```
$git log --pretty=oneline
[[33mab18ba3884244e99d99122e788062b2aaf6ba372[[m commit-21
[[33m9625c19e03a747457162d7c0274d75b154a0b926[[m commit-20
[[33m8668df12af9eee540cc29f9deb6d31d873bb8f24[[m commit-19
[[33m8315cd7962c902d39160fcf2fd018f249e7cf744[[m commit-18
[[33m3bcecc602a70fb60324777831d51c81b6f9ccaa7[[m commit-17
[[33m0485a39c37e72eabb4003e07a6b8cbae7a0d4e25[[m commit-16
[[33m9d3b04a7bcbb82be8b6b7882511f8133745c93b6[[m commit-15
[[33m22c259497571390fdd1461f0dd6b77244851984b[[m commit-14
[[33m39fb965fc245be55bb86491b5871dd2def08fdf4[[m commit-13
[[33m299f6bb77e922d707c9981a48d4d75f57b724719[[m commit-12
[[33me7285377d7afc08c7a5fb0ca44154d2de7e1d275[[m commit-11
[[33mb3360786ef13044d13b6e58c2239cce5595a1abf[[m commit-10
[[33m9af4c134e0d239d1c34fc6bb6087f0473c187fd5[[m commit-9
[[33md55ac3370f506a4bbf8a4690b9285e5de9c6a671[[m commit-8
[[33me50ef5f58b18d05c36343114804d8be180d26bcb[[m commit-7
[[33m962e4a8de7649e06df29f9058a600f8318caf023[[m commit-6
[[33m37f5363f62a3f973fe6e0d516e47b4324186d998[[m commit-5
[[33m0033e32339e4dc0cce8bd208d43b18a4e9ab43d9[[m commit-4
[[33m345239c740a408826f1df0dc5592d5d6b355f019[[m commit-3
[[33m8c85bf2592f52302ff389a5b6af4127fbe04c73b[[m commit-2
[[33ma4077b6c2b6a491af72ae3afc3b5c6260090b605[[m commit-1
```

What I want to do is effectively delete the last 3 commits and end up with this:(So it was like git commit 19, 20 and 21 never happened)

```
$git log --pretty=oneline
[[33m8315cd7962c902d39160fcf2fd018f249e7cf744[[m commit-18
[[33m3bcecc602a70fb60324777831d51c81b6f9ccaa7[[m commit-17
[[33m0485a39c37e72eabb4003e07a6b8cbae7a0d4e25[[m commit-16
[[33m9d3b04a7bcbb82be8b6b7882511f8133745c93b6[[m commit-15
[[33m22c259497571390fdd1461f0dd6b77244851984b[[m commit-14
[[33m39fb965fc245be55bb86491b5871dd2def08fdf4[[m commit-13
[[33m299f6bb77e922d707c9981a48d4d75f57b724719[[m commit-12
[[33me7285377d7afc08c7a5fb0ca44154d2de7e1d275[[m commit-11
[[33mb3360786ef13044d13b6e58c2239cce5595a1abf[[m commit-10
[[33m9af4c134e0d239d1c34fc6bb6087f0473c187fd5[[m commit-9
[[33md55ac3370f506a4bbf8a4690b9285e5de9c6a671[[m commit-8
[[33me50ef5f58b18d05c36343114804d8be180d26bcb[[m commit-7
[[33m962e4a8de7649e06df29f9058a600f8318caf023[[m commit-6
[[33m37f5363f62a3f973fe6e0d516e47b4324186d998[[m commit-5
[[33m0033e32339e4dc0cce8bd208d43b18a4e9ab43d9[[m commit-4
[[33m345239c740a408826f1df0dc5592d5d6b355f019[[m commit-3
[[33m8c85bf2592f52302ff389a5b6af4127fbe04c73b[[m commit-2
[[33ma4077b6c2b6a491af72ae3afc3b5c6260090b605[[m commit-1
```

**Note:**
I have looked into this and can't quiet get what I want. I have tried [git revert](https://nakkaya.com/2009/09/24/git-delete-last-commit/)(this is advise if I have published which I presume is the same as `git push -u origin master`) `git rebase` [git reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338728/delete-commits-from-a-branch-in-git)
I am not concerned with my remote at this stage I jsut want to get my local repo put back a couple of repos.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to undo last commit(s) in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-last-commits-in-git)

Answer (score 113, accepted):

use can use `git reset` for that

```
git reset --hard HEAD~3

git push --force origin master
```

where `HEAD~3` means *go back 3 commits*

You can also use the commit number instead of *3 commits*, so that you are sure where you are going back in time, like

```
git reset --hard 8315cd7962c902d39160fcf2fd018f249e7cf744
```

EDIT:

When rewriting history, prefer using

```
git push origin +master
```

To be safe if you are ever pushing more than one branch. You can read more at [Git Force push syntax, "-f" versus "+branch"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25937730/git-force-push-syntax-f-versus-branch)

(kudor to [Josef Kufner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1854924/josef-kufner) comment pointing it out)

EDIT 2:

I just noticed that your log is printing colors as codes, So

```
git reset -- hard 33m8315cd7962c902d39160fcf2fd018f249e7cf744
```

will not work, `[[33m` and `[[m` are color codes! So your commit number is actually `8315cd7962c902d39160fcf2fd018f249e7cf744`

If you do

```
git reset --hard 8315cd7962c902d39160fcf2fd018f249e7cf744
```

it should work as well.

(Fixed the commit code on previous examples as well)

Comment: It is better to use `git push origin +master`, because when/if you push multiple branches, you will not overwrite some by accident.

Comment: tks tried this `git reset --hard 33m8315cd7962c902d39160fcf2fd018f249e7cf744` and this `git reset -- hard 33m8315cd7962c902d39160fcf2fd018f249e7cf744` and did not work. But this `git reset --hard HEAD~3` and this `git push origin +master` did work.

Comment: Oh! I just noticed that your log is printing colors as codes, that's why `git reset -- hard 33m8315cd7962c902d39160fcf2fd018f249e7cf744` did no work, `[[33m` and `[[m` are color codes! SO your commit number is actually  `8315cd7962c902d39160fcf2fd018f249e7cf744` If you do `git reset --hard 8315cd7962c902d39160fcf2fd018f249e7cf744` it should work as well :)

Comment: @HattrickNZ oh, and please mark it as accepted if this is the answer you think is the correct. Thanks :)

Comment: struggled for days but this one worked for me ... Thanks Felipe

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by reverting your chanages by using git reset command and for commit to server as below

```
git reset --hard commitID

git reset --hard 6e58a7ff2abf317257df87e1eda72b3e8f78735a


git push --force origin +branchName

git push --force origin +feature/s2-stored-procedure
```