# What does "the normal fast-forward safety check" mean for `git fetch, pull, and push`?

Tags: git

*Version Control with Git* says

> The syntax of a refspec is:
>
> ```
> [+]source:destination
> ```
>
> It consists primarily of a source ref, a colon (:), and a destination
>   ref. The whole format may be prefixed with an optional plus sign (+).
>   If present, the plus sign indicates that the normal fast-forward
>   safety check will not be performed during the transfer.

What does "the normal fast-forward safety check" mean for `git fetch, pull, and push`?

What is the implication of not performing it during the transfer?

Comment: `man git-fetch` describes `<refspec` and explains the semantics of `+`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25937730/git-force-push-syntax-f-versus-branch/25937833#25937833