# git push -f --mirror - Where did all the Other Branches Go?

Tags: git

I noticed that after renaming a local branch of mine using the command `git push -f --mirror`, it renamed it successfully on the remote repo too, however all the other branches disappeared that were up there.  Either it's a coincidence when I refreshed our repo when viewing the branches for the remote repo in BitBucket,(they were gone, maybe someone deleted theirs) or this command did something unexpected that I'm not aware of yet

would this command do such a thing and what would that mean?  What happened?

Comment: Don't use `git push -f --mirror` to rename a local branch! Use `git branch -m <old-name> <new-name>` instead. The `-f` flag should be used with great care; don't use it willy-nilly.

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be the documented behavior of the `--mirror` option:

> `--mirror`
>
> Instead of naming each ref to push, specifies that all refs under
>   refs/ (which includes but is not limited to refs/heads/,
>   refs/remotes/, and refs/tags/) be mirrored to the remote
>   repository. Newly created local refs will be pushed to the remote
>   end, locally updated refs will be force updated on the remote end,
>   **and deleted refs will be removed from the remote end.**

A deleted ref means "one that is not in your local repository".

Answer (score 0):

For anyone being as desperate as me after executing `git push -f --mirror` accidentally and deleting a lot of branches:
Try to get hold of the latest ref/commit-hashs of all branches. In my case I got an email for every deleted branch with the latest ref in it.
Then execute `git checkout -b <branch-name> <ref>` for every deleted branch for recover them locally. By this only these changes get lost, that happened after your last `git fetch`
After recovering all branches locally, you can just `git push origin <branch-name>` them again to recover them on the remote.