# How to completely erase a git push from history?

Tags: git, push, revert, gogs

I accidentally pushed something I didn't want to to a repository. I followed the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1270608/6639282) but, although it did revert the code, there's still a log of what happened that I wish to erase: [image: the log]

To clarify, I want things to be as though everything after commit 1a869f3c6d simply never happened.

I have full access to the server where this repository is hosted, so I can manually modify some of the configuration files if necessary. And I don't know if this is really relevant, but the git server being used is Go Git Service.

Disclaimer: I understand why I may not want to do this. If you're only going to respond with why it's a bad idea, please don't.

Answer (score 1):

To back out the latest commit on master, use `git reset --hard`:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard master~1
git push -f
```

Or if you know the commit you want `master` to point to:

```
git reset --hard 1a869f3c6d
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this does still leave the traces of the two pushes as shown in the image. The more I think about it, the likelier it seems that I will have to manually modify some of the files on the server...