# Undo git push - local commit not reverted

Tags: git, github

I have 3 commits(c1, c2 and c3) to a branch (b).

c3 is a bad commit. As I wanted to revert to c2 so I have [undo the git push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270514/undoing-a-git-push) using following command

```
cd /path/to/project (branch: b)
git push -f origin c2:b
```

remotely my branch is reverted to c2, but locally I still have c3. I tried

```
git pull origin b
```

Result

```
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

How can I revert to my good_commit (c2) locally ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [reset](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) the branch to the commit

```
git reset --hard c2
```