# How can I reject push from repository members using GitHub Actions?

Tags: git, github, github-actions

My task is as follows: Upon receive of a new commits (by single push), it is necessary to perform a github action, which would send the task to test on a test server via ssh (with `git pull` and `npm test`). Then, if testing fails, this push (all commits in it) should be canceled.

With the first part, it seems, there are no problems, but I can’t figure out how to implement the second part, that is, canceling the push. Thank you for your attention to the question!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undoing a 'git push'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270514/undoing-a-git-push)

Comment: Not a duplicate of [Undoing a 'git push'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270514/undoing-a-git-push) because this question is specifically about writing a GitHub Actions workflow.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can't use GitHub Actions to prevent a push; you would need a pre-receive hook to do that.  GitHub's cloud version doesn't currently support that, although GitHub Enterprise Server (the on-premises version) does.

However, what you can do, and what it sounds like you probably want to do based on your use of `npm test`, is to run a CI job on push and restrict the `master` branch.  You can use GitHub Actions to automatically test your code when a pull request is opened and require that all checks pass before it can be merged.  Since the `master` branch cannot be pushed to directly, it wouldn't be possible to avoid the CI job.

If you're the only contributor to the project, you can just push your branch to your repository, let the CI job run, and then do a fast-forward merge into `master` if the job passes.  This is a little more work, but you don't have to open any pull requests.

Comment: could you point me to an example on how to `run a CI job on push and restrict the master branch`

Comment: Very well explained.