# How to revert back a last push on the git branch?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have many `branches` on my repo. I accidentally pushed to branch named `feature/customer`. Now I want to roll back that push. How can I rollback that push on branch `feature/customer` in git?

Comment: Do you want to remove the branch you pushed to the remote?

Comment: No, this branch has lots of code already. I just pushed some wrong code on this branch. Now i want to revert only my last push on this branch

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270514/undoing-a-git-push

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `feature/customer` branch is shared by other people, and that someone else may have already pulled your accidental commit, the best thing to do would be to *revert* the commit:

```
# from feature/customer
git revert HEAD
```

This will add a *new* commit on top of the `customer` branch which will functionally undo whatever your accidental commit may have introduced.  Now you only need to do a regular push again to get this revert commit to the repository.

Note that if the accidental commit contains any sensitive information, you *could* try to overwrite the remote branch.  However, there would always still be the possibility that someone else already pulled.  In addition, the previous accidental commit would still be present in the remote reflog for some time.

Comment: what this means? `# from feature/customer`

Comment: @ahsan Comments in Git start with `#` ... this is just a comment

Comment: so i have to stand on branch `feature/customer` and run this command `# from feature/customer`? and what will do this command? will it undo my last push on this branch?

Comment: Please refer to my previous comment :-)

Comment: I didn't get you properly. Please answer my previous comment

Answer (score 0):

If you have permissions on the remote. You can do the following:

```
git push -f origin last_known_good_commit:branch_name
```

Also, you can refer to [Undoing a 'git push'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270514/undoing-a-git-push)