# How to undo the last commit on GitHub?

Tags: github, commit, undo, git-revert

I want to undo the last commit pushed to GitHub on the master branch of a repository, and make it so that it's as if this commit never existed and doesn't appear in the commit history.

How do I go about this?

Note to those voting to close — the proposed alternative questions are needlessly complex, have condescending answers, and are littered with giant walls of text that are difficult to sift through.

Hence, this simple question with a simple answer for my benefit and that of posterity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undoing a 'git push'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270514/undoing-a-git-push)

Comment: My question is already answered, but thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you wish to rewind the master branch of the repository to a previous pushed commit, simply run this command — of course, with the appropriate commit hash:

```
git reset --hard a0b1c2d3e4f5g6h7i8j9k0l1m2n3o4p5q6r7s8t9
git push --force
```

This may have unintended consequences if, for instance, there are collaborators on your repository.  But, I am sure you know what you're doing

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the `--force` argument.

You can reset to a specific commit with `git reset --hard {commit sha}` and then force the change to origin with `git push --force`.

Note that if others are using your repo, they will need to use `git pull --force` or they may inadvertently put your unwanted commit back into the repo.

I recommend reading the help documentation for `git reset` and `git push` before taking action.