# git-diff in another directory

Tags: git, zsh

I'm currently writing a little zsh function that checks all of my git repositories to see if they're dirty or not and then prints out the ones that need a commit.  Thus far, I've figured out that the quickest way to figure out a git repository's clean/dirty status is via `git-diff` and `git-ls-files`:

```
if ! git diff --quiet || git ls-files --others --exclude-standard; then
  state=":dirty"
fi
```

I have two questions for you folks:

1. Does anyone know of a quicker, more efficient way to check for file changes/additions in a git repo?
2. I want my zsh function to be handed a file path (say `~/Code/git-repos/`) and check all of the repositories in it.  Is there a way to do without having to cd into each directory and run those commands?  Something like `git-diff --quiet --git-dir="~/Code/git-repos/..."` would be fantastic.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657935/checking-for-a-dirty-index-or-untracked-files-with-git help?

Comment: @VonC - that looks great.  I was hoping that I wouldn't have to use git-status, since it's a bit heavier, but it it allows me to specify "remote" git directories to look in, it may be my only choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `$DIR` holds your directory name and it's a standard layout (i.e. the `.git` dir is `$DIR/.git`), then `git --git-dir $DIR/.git --work-tree $DIR status -s -uno` will list all the files that have uncommitted changes. Checking if the list is empty should give you what you want.

Comment: Running that command gives "fatal: Invalid untracked files mode '=none'."  The man page specifies 'no' as a valid option for -u, but that gives a similar error.

Comment: You're right, sorry, the syntax was slightly off. Use -uno instead of -u=none

Comment: (I fixed the post accordingly)

Comment: A combination of this and @VonC's link above (in particular, the --porcelain flag for git status) is what did the trick.