# git commit metrics

Tags: git, bash, metrics

I want to determine git commit metrics  using  bash script.
But I never use bash script.

The idea is to have **the number of commit wich are not referenced in their status during a specific time**
(i.e.: not closed or no `#nnnn` reference where `n` is a number, because we use Redmine to show the reference of open commit)

the algorithm is:

```
fonction (initial date, final date)
  read initial date
  read final date
  int n=0
  while (initial date<date<final date) do 
    if (status!=closed or status!= #nnnn) //where #nnnn is a reference and n a number
      n=+1
    end if
  end while
  echo "the number of none referenced commit is"
  echo n 
  return 0
```

If there is a specific git command or other idea, please leave a response, it will help me a lot. thank you

Answer (score 1):

#### *Update* After the comments:

It seems you really are helped by the much simpler

```
git log --oneline | egrep -ivw 'closed|#[0123456789]+'
```

filtering out just common patterns from commit messages. If you wanted a count of that

```
git log --oneline | egrep -ivwc 'closed|#[0123456789]+'
```

You can add from the original answer flags to reduce the output of `git log`, like so

```
git log --oneline --after=2011-01-01 --until=today | egrep -ivwc 'closed|#[0123456789]+'
```

---

#### Original answer:

Come again. This question does not parse. *"wich are not referenced in their status"* What status? A commit doesn't normally have one. Are you using commit notes?

I'm getting the impression you want to find certain information that was *not* mentioned in git commit messages during a specific period of time? If so, give examples of what kind of commit messages you use, and how the list of 'relation ids' to look for is stored. E.g.:

```
from="3 months ago"
until="1 week ago"

lookforids=( '#bug3' '#update4' '#featureY' )
for lookfor in "${lookforids[@]}";
do
    commitcount=$(git log --no-merges --oneline --after="$from" --until="$until" --all -i --grep="$lookfor" | wc -l)

    if [ "$commitcount" -le 1 ]; then echo "Not referenced: $lookfor"; fi
done
```

Of course you should mix and match to your needs, altering the output to your liking. `from`/`until` can of course be absolute date literals if you like.

Comment: I would *not* use a porcelain command (`git log`) in a script, but otherwise I agree with your idea. +1

Comment: Mind you that I simply took a stab at the requirements here. No sense in perfecting a useless solution yet :) I'll await the OP response and work from there

Comment: On the porcelain vs. plumbing part, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878624/how-do-i-programmatically-determine-if-there-are-uncommited-changes/3879077#3879077 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657935/checking-for-a-dirty-index-or-untracked-files-with-git/2659808#2659808

Comment: I'm here no longer(it is an internship), so i didn't know if they use commit note or not but in the different commit informations after doing <<git log>> there is this characteristic: closes: #3444 for example or only #3444 the number permit to trace a feature, but some people doesn't add this number after the commit so the idea is to have the number of commit wich are not referenced by closes or #nnnn where n is an integer. and thank you for your first response

Comment: `'#bug3' '#update4' '#featureY'` are just examples of strings that you could look for, since you didn't specify any :). Your new question in the comment would be simply `git log --oneline | egrep -iv 'closed|#[0123456789]+'` ...

Comment: i try it but, i have many git comment, but is it possible to have only a number, but a number of the opposite of <<git log --oneline | egrep -iv 'closed|#[0123456789]+'>> result; because this command give me all of the commit wich contain closed or #[0123456789]+ but i need the commit wich don't contain closed or #[0123456789]+, it will be cool if i have the number of this commit type...for example <<148 commit without closed or #[0123456789]+>>...thank you a lot for your help

Comment: @user703681; You didn't try it (correctly). I think it time for you to read some man pages: [`egrep -v or --invert-match`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?egrep)

Comment: Please remove the confusing comments, I will update my answer shortly. **I do think that the next thing you should read is a [beginner's course in `bash](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Teaching/Unix/)** (_and possibly more on [bash](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/)_ If you can't figure out how to copy simple command options, you will have a very hard time getting things done, or even asking questions.

Comment: thank you for the guide, excuse me but i am a beginner in this language.

Answer (score 1):

Such a script would use and exploit the git low-level commands (plumbing, suitable for scripting) command **[`git rev-list`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html)**:

The **commit limiting options** allow you to define a range of date, and to select the right log message:

```
--skip=<number>
    Skip number commits before starting to show the commit output.
--since=<date>
--after=<date>
    Show commits more recent than a specific date.
--until=<date>
--before=<date>
    Show commits older than a specific date.
--max-age=<timestamp>
--min-age=<timestamp>
    Limit the commits output to specified time range.

--grep=<pattern>
```

> Limit the commits output to ones with log message that matches the specified pattern (regular expression).

The **commit formatting options** allow you to display only what you need, mainly the comment of the commit, for you to parse (I suppose it is in the comment of a commit that you have stored the status of said commit, although you could also have used **[`git notes`](http://progit.org/2010/08/25/notes.html)**):

```
--pretty[=<format>]
--format=<format>
```

> Pretty-print the contents of the commit logs in a given format, where  can be one of oneline, short, medium, full, fuller, email, raw and format:. See the "PRETTY FORMATS" section for some additional details for each format. When omitted, the format defaults to medium.

Comment: I try for example  git rev-list --after=10/02/20 or  git rev-list --after=<10/02/20> or  git rev-list --after="10/02/20" but nothing

Comment: @user703681: I suspect an issue in the date format: try `YYYY-MM-DD` as in '`--after=2010-02-20`'. No quote or '`<`' or '`>`' should be necessary around the date.