# gitlab-ci testing build failed

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-pipelines

I am new to gitlab-ci and I am trying to test my build phase but it keeps failing before last step. here is the section

```
build:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - git config user.name "$GITLAB_USER_NAME"
    - git config user.email "$GITLAB_USER_EMAIL"
  script:
    - git add .
    - git commit -m "[skip ci] migrations"
    - git push "https://${GITLAB_USER_NAME}:${CI_GIT_TOKEN}@${CI_REPOSITORY_URL}" "HEAD:qa" -o ci.skip
  dependencies:
    - migrations
  only:
    - qa
```

This is the log, last few lines

```
Using docker image sha256:5b3b4504ff1f7b859dbc5d7fb86f4afc644be62f99b8ced636fbca64c8a6c2de for python:latest with digest python@sha256:73cc381fa0fe5e6d5dd38f1397da28c70096519d8818c2249f2bc8e1158ba015 ...
$ git config user.name "$GITLAB_USER_NAME"
$ git config user.email "$GITLAB_USER_EMAIL"
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "[skip ci] migrations"
HEAD detached at bf2a8e4
nothing to commit, working tree clean
Cleaning up file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

How can I find out what `ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1` is? I am using shared runners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1` is coming from git not finding anything to commit. In other words, the below message is causing the error:

```
nothing to commit, working tree clean
Cleaning up file based variables
```

You can either may sure there is something to commit, or you can adjust your script as outlined in this related thread: [How to git commit nothing without an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123674/how-to-git-commit-nothing-without-an-error)