# Git commit works from command line, but fails from golang code

Tags: git, go, git-worktree

I am trying to execute the code mentioned below. The code creates a branch, and then a worktree and commit is done from worktree directory

The code fails with below error:

```
error= exit status 1
```

If I execute the commit (Cmd3) directly from command line, it works fine:

```
sh-3.2# /usr/bin/git -C /Users/gitissue/folder1/Outer commit -m Commiting-from-folder1-Outer
On branch Outer
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Steps:

1. Created folder /Users/gitissue
2. cd /Users/gitissue
3. git init
4. touch t.txt
5. git add .
6. git commit -m "commit"
7. mkdir -p /Users/gitissue/folder1
8. execute go code mentioned below

Env details:

- MAC OS
- git version 2.37.0
- go version go1.18.1 darwin/amd64

Code:

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"io"
exec "os/exec"
)

func main() {

Cmd := exec.Command("git", "-C", "/Users/gitissue", "branch", "Outer")
fmt.Print("Cmd1= " + Cmd.String())
err := execBashCmd(Cmd)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Print("error1= " + err.Error())
}


Cmd = exec.Command("git", "-C", "/Users/gitissue/folder1", "worktree", "add", "Outer", "Outer")
fmt.Print("Cmd2= " + Cmd.String())
err = execBashCmd(Cmd)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Print("error2= " + err.Error())
}

Cmd = exec.Command("git", "-C", "/Users/gitissue/folder1/Outer", "commit", "-m", "Commiting-from-folder1-Outer")
fmt.Print("Cmd3= " + Cmd.String())

err = execBashCmd(Cmd)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Print("error3= " + err.Error())
}

}

func execBashCmd(cmd *exec.Cmd) error {

stderr, _ := cmd.StderrPipe()

if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
    fmt.Print("error= " + err.Error())
}

slurp, _ := io.ReadAll(stderr)
fmt.Printf("%s\n", slurp)

if slurp != nil {
}

if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
    fmt.Print("error= " + err.Error())
    return err
}
return nil
```

}

Output of above code:

```
Cmd1= /usr/bin/git -C /Users/gitissue branch Outer
Cmd2= /usr/bin/git -C /Users/gitissue/folder1 worktree add Outer OuterPreparing worktree (checking out 'Outer')

Cmd3= /usr/bin/git -C /Users/gitissue/folder1/Outer commit -m Commiting-from-folder1-Outer
error= exit status 1error3= exit status 1
```

Comment: Grab the [`CombinedOutput`](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Cmd.CombinedOutput) from each command and see what is causing it to error out.

Comment: error= exec: already startedpanic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x18 pc=0x1075854]

`cmd.Wait()` should close it, right? I tried adding some time.sleep(), but doesn't help

Comment: Your code has no concurrency so I don't see why a sleep would help.  That output implies you have a `nil` value somewhere, which should have been in the original output of your code.

Comment: Related, possibly even a dup: [How to git commit nothing without an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8123674/184546)

Comment: `Cmd = exec.Command("git", "-C", "/Users/gitissue/folder1/Outer", "commit", "-m", "Commiting-from-folder1-Outer")`

 `stdoutStderr, err := Cmd.CombinedOutput()`

Comment: Output:

sh-3.2# go run hello.go 
Cmd1= /usr/bin/git -C /Users/gitissue branch Outer
Cmd2= /usr/bin/git -C /Users/gitissue/folder1 worktree add Outer OuterPreparing worktree (checking out 'Outer')

`Cmd3= /usr/bin/git -C /Users/gitissue/folder1/Outer commit -m Commiting-from-folder1-Outer
Std Out and err:- On branch Outer
nothing to commit, working tree clean`

Comment: @Adrian, I misunderstood Cmd.CombinedOutput(). I added that, but did not comment the execBash earlier. So basically if I change the code as above, commenting execBash, the commit works fine. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 5):

There is no error at all. When there is nothing to commit, Git exits with exit code 1.

As described in the [documentation for Go wait()](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Cmd.Wait), "the returned error is nil if the command runs, has no problems copying stdin, stdout, and stderr, **and exits with a zero exit status**."

If you want, you can wrap around the error to see if it implements the method ExitCode(), which means the error generated was because of a non-zero exit code, and then if the exit code was 1, ignore it (or you could use any other type of logic to handle this situation).

```golang
if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
    if e, ok := err.(interface{ExitCode() int}); ok {
        if e.ExitCode() != 1 {
            // exit code is neither zero (as we have an error) or one
            fmt.Print("error= " + err.Error())
            return err
        }
    } else {
        return err
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Marc. The commit is indeed successful, because if I check `git log` from /Users/gitissue/folder1/Outer , it shows a commit.