# git: programmatically test if index is dirty

Tags: git, bash

I am writing a script which will do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysqldump -u user -p database > db_file
git add db_file
git commit -m 'db_file updated by script'
```

However, what if the index is dirty when I run this script? That is, what if I already `git add`ed files that I want to not have automatically committed when this script runs? I could do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysqldump -u user -p database > db_file
git stash
git add db_file
git commit -m 'db_file updated by script'
git stash apply
```

But now the problem is that if the index and working tree is *not* dirty, then git stash doesn't add anything to the stash list, but `git stash apply` will incorrectly apply whatever is on top of the stash and discard the history of that stash.

How can I make a bash conditional based on if the index is dirty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git diff --cached --quiet`

Previous answer:

`git diff --cached` will show exactly what I want to know. The only problem is that the return value is true no matter what, so it's hard to make a conditional off of that. If there is not better answer, then I can dump the output to a file and make a condition on if the file is empty or not. But that sounds painfully hack-ish. Surely there is a better way.

Comment: `git diff --cached --quiet`?

Comment: `--quiet`:
Disable all output of the program. Implies `--exit-code`. That is, it exits with 1 if there were differences and 0 means no differences.
[Docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)

Answer (score 1):

You could parse the output of `git status -s`.

```
if git status -s | grep -q '^.M'
then
    # ...
fi
```

Comment: For anyone else looking at this question later, I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657935/checking-for-a-dirty-index-or-untracked-files-with-git has a more robust solution.

Comment: This is horribly hackish. Git provides [low-level "plumbing" commands](http://schacon.github.com/git/git.html#_low_level_commands_plumbing) for this sort of thing exactly so you *don't* do something like this.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: A constructive comment would recommend an alternative. Which plumbing command would you suggest?

Comment: @Greg funnily enough, a "plumbing-like" command (ie able to be parsed in a script) would be... `git status -z --porcelain` (!), as I mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/6978402/6309

Comment: @VonC: ...and people say Git's command set is inconsistent. I can't imagine why! I wonder whether a patch to introduce `git status --plumbing` meaning the same as `--porcelain` (and deprecating `--porcelain` but not removing it) would be worthwhile.

Comment: @Greg: do you have any reference for this so-called "consistency" advocated by people? Because I have many references pointing out to the contrary. Including a recent one: http://www.saintsjd.com/2012/01/a-better-ui-for-git/ (first result of a google search on 'git commands consistent'...)

Comment: @VonC: I'm afraid my sarcasm may have not come across in my comment. Of course the Git command set is *inconsistent*, I don't think anybody would disagree with that.

Comment: @Greg: sorry, I shouldn't post comment in the middle of my other daily tasks ;) sarcasm acknowledged.

Comment: @GregHewgill I think the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657935/checking-for-a-dirty-index-or-untracked-files-with-git) that I had already suggested this question was a duplicate of provides a [good, in-depth solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2659808/211563). The OP also linked to that question as the first comment on this answer. My comment was to be taken in the context of this entire question.

Comment: I wasted about an hour trying to figure out how to figure out whether there are any changes. This is the best option I've seen, so this is what I'm going with until someone comes up with something better... This should not be so hard -.-

Comment: Okay, I'm actually doing it like this: `test -z "$(git status --porcelain)"`