# How to use git to check if local folder contains changes

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

Is there a catch-all way to use git to detect if any of the files in the current folder have changed compared to some specified git "base" revision? It should detect:
- any modified files which have not been staged
- any staged files which have not yet been committed
- any files committed more recently than the revison in question.

Basically what we try to achieve if to figure out, for a specific project, if the code on our development machine is the same as was built by our build server. In which case we could save time by skippping the build and instead downloading the build artefact from our maven repository (assuming that the build server installed it there). It's still mostly an idea and there may be a thousand reasons why it wouldn't work out but one of the first things to figure out is if git could provide information on which projects are basically unchanged.

Thanks,
/Martin

Comment: [git diff](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git describe --dirty` may cover your requirements. It will produce a description of the current working tree in terms of the previous tag, with possible suffixes for extra commits on top or `-dirty` if files have been modified and not committed.

If the result is a valid version tag for your project then you should be able to use that build.

If you need finer control, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2659808/733345 for how to also check for untracked files.