# Stop git from allowing me to switch branches with uncommitted changes

Tags: git

I understand the behaviour (and usefulness) of being able to switch branches when you have uncommitted changes. However, in 99.9% of my workflow this is undesirable because it means I've forgotten to commit changes before switching to a different feature branch. Is there a setting somewhere that I can set to either not allow a switch with uncommitted changes or to at least give a warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There does not seem to be a config for that case (checkout with a dirty index).

That leaves you with writing a script `git-co` (which can be called as `git co`) which will:

- check for modified or untracked files (see "[Checking for a dirty index or untracked files with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2658301/6309)")
- do the checkout only if the index is clean.

Note: [there is no pre-checkout hook](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Why-there-is-no-pre-checkout-hook-td5638042.html), even though [one was proposed in 2009](http://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg114525.html).

Comment: It's a shame that this isn't possible, but thanks for the information.

Comment: are there any news to this? I'd love to get this behaviour on my projects

Comment: @Raphael_S Check out (pun not intended) the new checkout command `git switch`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24384951/confused-by-git-checkout/57066202#57066202. For common files, it will block the switch. Fir for files which are modified, but not common with the destination branch, however... the switch might still occur.