# github actions checking for changes in git using git diff

Tags: github-actions

I have the following part of a `.yml` file. `Check for changes` runs but `Commit and push changes` is never run, even when changes were clearly done before `Check for changes` is run. I don't know why git diff is not detecting these changes... Could you help me?

```
      - name: Check for changes
        id: check_changes
        run: |
          git diff --exit-code
          if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "No changes to commit."
            echo "::set-output name=changes::false"
          else
            echo "::set-output name=changes::true"
          fi

      - name: Commit and push changes
        if: steps.check_changes.outputs.changes == 'true'
        run: |
          git config --global user.email "${GITHUB_ACTOR_ID}+${GITHUB_ACTOR}@users.noreply.github.com"
          git config --global user.name "${GITHUB_ACTOR}"

          git add .
          git commit -m "Created github pages docs"
          git push origin master
```

Comment: "even when changes were clearly done before Check for changes is run". Could you show the part where you make the changes that should result in a diff?

Comment: unfortunately I can't... But I see it was changing by running `ls` right before git diff... I create a folder and the folder created is actually there. Maybe I can use `mkdir` and make a better example of this.

Comment: Does the folder have anything in it? Git does not show a diff for added empty folders.

Comment: yes, it has. Not empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @hakre mentioned already, `git diff --exit-code` won't throw an exit code for untracked files, i.e. completely new files.

If you are in previous steps creating completely new directories, as you mentioned, then this is the case for you.

You can use the following command to check for untracked files.

```
      - name: Check for changes
        id: check_changes
        run: |
          if [[ -n $(git status --porcelain) ]]; then
              echo "changes=true" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"; 
          fi
```

See [Checking for a dirty index or untracked files with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657935/checking-for-a-dirty-index-or-untracked-files-with-git) for more details.

Note also that `::set-output` is deprecated, using `$GITHUB_OUTPUT` is the recommended and much cleaner way.

Answer (score 2):

the shell may quit early (set -e), but not within an if:

```
  - name: Check for changes
    id: check_changes
    run: |
      if git diff --exit-code; then
        echo "No changes to commit."
        echo "::set-output name=changes::false"
      else
        echo "::set-output name=changes::true"
      fi
```

And if the folder you create is not under version control tracking already, `git diff` won't care about it.

You perhaps want to use a git command like `git-status` that is looking for untracked files.