How to split a commit into two without introducing merge conflicts?
I had lines like this to change:
service.audit(Message.delete()[…] [long line]

I had to add withMessage(…) to them where that was missing.  At the
same time I formatted the places where the lines were long:
service.audit(Message.
    .delete()
    .withMessage([…])
    .withUser(…)
    .withPayload(…)
    […]

Now I want to split this commit into two:

Format
Add new method

But if I do a split in the standard way, say with:

Do an interactive rebase
Reset on the commit
Stage the changes I want:

Remove the call withMessage(…) from the staged changes/index,
leaving just the formatting changes
Commit


Cherry-pick the old commit

I get merge conflicts since I did changes in the same places.

We’re not gonna use git-rebase(1) and/or git-cherry-pick(1) since these
turn commits into patches in order to make new commits.  That’s why you
get merge conflicts.
Instead you want to make use of the fact that commits are snapshots.

You already have the snapshot you want to end up with: that is
currently your one and only commit, which will after the split become
the second commit
You can then craft the first commit by using the changes in the first
commit: manually remove the changes you don’t want and then commit
Make a new commit for the second change using the original (unsplit)
commit

More concretely:

Store the hash of the current commit (hash)
Do a reset back one commit
Remove the withMessage(…) lines
Commit
Make a commit hash and the parent set to the current commit (the first
commit in the split; HEAD)

#!/usr/bin/env bash

hash=$(git rev-parse @)
# Safely do `git reset`
# See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2659808/1725151
git diff-index --quiet --cached HEAD -- \
    || { printf "staged changes: refusing to check out"; exit 1; }
git diff-files --quiet \
    || { printf "unstaged changes: refusing to check out"; exit 1; }
git reset --soft @~1
# Manipulate the staged changes
# Give a shell prompt to pause and allow that
printf "Stage your changes and then type ‘exit’\n"
sh
# You can edit the commit message with an interactive rebase afterwards
git commit -msplit
# Add back the original commit
git restore -SW -s "$hash" -- .
git commit -C"$hash"

Work backwards instead of forwards
In this case it helps to keep the state of the starting point and then
move one step backwards.  Since you have the desired end-state already
the only manual work is to remove things from what will become the first
commit of the two.
Contrast with a rebase session where you go back N commits, change to
the state you want back at that point, and then deal with merge
conflicts (if overlapping) as you apply the changes forwards.
Use git-rebase(1) for touchups like changing the commit messages
It’s natural that the commit messages will change after a split.  We
leave that for later:

Use a placeholder message “split” on the new first commit (git commit -msplit)
Keep the original commit message on the second commit

Since we can already change the commit messages easily in a rebase
session: there are no possible conflicts any more so we can just focus
on that part.
Generalization
This script splits the current commit you are on.  What if you want to do a split N commits back?

Do an interactive rebase
Mark the commit you want to split for editing (edit)
Do this procedure
git rebase --continue

(Thanks to j6t)

your script is missing the step after git commit -msplit. I don't see the use for a git merge command, something like git restore -SW -s "$hash" -- . && git commit -C"$hash" should be enough.

@LeGEC Thank  you

To split a commit N steps back in the history, use interactive rebase to stop at the commit to split, do the procedure outlined here, then continue the rebase. Then follow up with another rebase that fixes the commit messages.

Thanks @j6t. I will update the answer later. (I did also think of that this morning, I swear! :P)

Yup, using git-restore(1) and git-commit(1) is easier than git-commit-tree(1). Having to pipe in the commit message is a bit fiddly/hard to read.
