# How do I find out which version I've got checked out in git?

Tags: git, parent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to retrieve the hash for the current commit in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949314/how-to-retrieve-the-hash-for-the-current-commit-in-git)

I.e. what's the git equivalent of `hg parent` or `svn info`.

Extra points for an answer that I can use in a script, i.e. It gives 'bbh653ad' rather than a load of words which contain the version number somewhere

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the hash of the HEAD, use this command:

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

or for the short form:

```
git rev-parse --short HEAD
```

If you have tags and you are looking for a more descriptive revision number, you can consider using the result of the command:

```
git describe --long
```

Comment: long form particularly useful as it shows tags names.