# git: How do I get the hash of the latest commit in the current branch when in detached HEAD state?

Tags: git

How do I get the hash of the latest commit...

1. when in detached HEAD state
2. without specifying the branch explicitly

`git rev-parse HEAD` and `git log -n 1 --format="%H"` both follow the detached HEAD (obviously).

`git rev-parse master` has me typing in the branch.

I'm guessing that the detached HEAD state has no notion of branches, but do you see my intention? I've been in master the whole time so I don't want to have to specify it explicitly just because I'm looking at a previous commit.

Same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15677439/how-to-get-latest-git-commit-hash-command) but for detached HEAD state.

Thanks!

Comment: what happens if you git pull origin branchname

Comment: @m79lkm requires typing in the branchname, which I'm trying to avoid

Comment: Indeed; a detached head is not on any branch at all, so there's no way to tell you otherwise.  Could you explain your workflow a bit more to explain how you get into this situation and what you want to see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A problem is that the commit you are on (detached from the head) may actually be on several branches.  If you only want *one* branch to be presented, you'll have to figure out some way to choose between them.  But if you're happy seeing all the branches (with hashes) that contain your current commit you can say

```
git branch -v --contains HEAD
```

Here's some example output:

```
* (detached from 0bc85ab) 0bc85ab Git 1.9.2
  master                  cc29195 Git 2.0-rc0
```

you could trim that with grep and/or awk.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies why I can't assume the detached HEAD is in a particular branch. I found the following code which works similarly and trims the output as you suggested: `git show-ref | grep $(git show-ref -s -- HEAD) | sed 's|.*/\(.*\)|\1|' | grep -v HEAD | sort | uniq`

Answer (score 0):

[To refer to "the *n*‍th previous branch I checked out", use `@{-n}`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).

```
git rev-parse @{-1}
```

This really is a branch reference:

```
git checkout @{-1}
```

will leave you on that branch.