# How do I get the output from a call to GIT into a variable in a batch script?

Tags: windows, git, batch-file

I have a git command to get the latest SHA of the current repo as follows:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%H" -n 1
```

I have a windows batch script I'd like to use this in as follows:

```
SET CURRENT_SHA=???
```

But I'm at a loss as to how to get the output from that call to git into the variable so that I can make use of it.

**Edit**

I've tried the following (which seems to be the general advice I've read here and elsewhere):

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%i IN (`git log --pretty=format:"%H" -n 1`) DO (SET CURRENT_SHA=%%i)
ECHO Current Sha: %CURRENT_SHA%
```

..but I get:

```
fatal: failed to stat 'format:i) ECHO Current Sha: 48bce83e800b96607afb2a387c4fcd7b0b0f037e
```

So presumably there's a problem with the quotes?

Comment: I think you need to double the percent to escape it for `%H` and then again because its in a batch file.

Comment: That and escaping the `=` was the ticket.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have a Windows system handy to test, but I think something along these lines:

```
FOR /F %i IN (`git log --pretty=format:"%%H" -n 1`) DO SET CURRENT_SHA=%i
```

Note that the "%H" needs to be escaped, but to use this line in a batch file you also need to double escape everything. You may also need to escape the double-quotes with `^`. I think this ought to work:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%a in (`git log --pretty^=format:"%%H" -n 1`) do (SET CURRENT_SHA=%%a)
ECHO Current Sha: %CURRENT_SHA%
```

But really, if you want to do shell programming in Windows just use Powershell and then you can do:

```
$CURRENT_SHA=git log --pretty=format:"%H" -n 1
```

Comment: You sir, are a legend. I finally got it working with `git log --pretty^=format:"%%H" -n 1` so it turns out it was the equals sign and a missing extra `%`