# How to get a result from a Puppet provisioner

Tags: git, puppet

We use the [Puppetlabs VCSRepo](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/vcsrepo) to checkout a repository. When this is done, we would like to push a notification containing the SHA of the new version. I have no clue how to get this.

We use the VCS Repo like this:

```
vcsrepo { "/opt/ourcompany/distribution":
    ensure   => latest,
    owner    => $owner,
    provider => git,
    require  => [ Package["git"], User["ouruser" ]],
    source   => "git@domain.com:our/repository.git",
    revision => 'master',
    user => $owner,
}
```

Then we set-up a notification like this:

```
exec { "send-hipchat-message" :
   command => "curl -d \"$body\" $url", #Parameters are set somewhere else
   path => "/usr/bin/",
   subscribe => Vcsrepo["/opt/ourcompany/distribution"],
   refreshonly => true
}
```

So the question is: how do I get the SHA of the revision the vcs repo has just updated to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just get SHA of latest commit you can use any of commands from another answer: [How to retrieve the hash for the current commit in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949314/how-to-retrieve-the-hash-for-the-current-commit-in-git)

After that you just need to modify your command in `exec` to invoke something like `git rev-parse HEAD` from directory with sources. Here simple example:

```
exec { "send-hipchat-message" :
   command     => "echo \"SHA: $$(git rev-parse HEAD)\"",
   path        => "/usr/bin",
   subscribe   => Vcsrepo["/opt/ourcompany/distribution"],
   require     => Vcsrepo["/opt/ourcompany/distribution"],
   cwd         => '/opt/ourcompany/distribution',
   refreshonly => true
}
```

Note to `cwd`, `require` and `command` attributes.