# Find executable that a core dump was generated against

Tags: c, linux, unix, elf

Is there a way to embed version info such as a git commit hash in an ELF executable such that it can be retrieved from core dumps generated from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/949314/841108) to get the git hash.

Then, change your build procedure (e.g. your `Makefile`) to include it. For instance, generate a one line C file with

```
  git log --pretty=format:'const char program_git_hash[] = "%H";' \
      -n 1 > _prog_hash.c
```

then link your program with `_prog_hash.c` and remove that file after linking.
You could add timestamping information with e.g.

```
 date +'const char program_timestamp="%c";%n' >> _prog_hash.c
```

Then you could use `gdb` or `strings` on the binary executable to find it.

You may want to declare `extern const char program_git_hash[];` in some header file, and perhaps display it (e.g. when passing the `--version` option to your program)

Comment: I found that running "strings <my_core_dump_file>" and then searching for my git commit hash from the output solved the problem after following the above steps.