# How to retrieve commit hash of latest available version in repo

Tags: git

I know how to get the commit hash for the current version of the local repo ([How to retrieve the hash for the current commit in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949314/how-to-retrieve-the-hash-for-the-current-commit-in-git)).

Given a branch name, possibly different from the local repos branch, is there a way to get the long hash of the latest available version in the remote repo without actually doing a clone or pull?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/949314/1761003)

Comment: @maveň That's the post I linked to. I'll scour over it again but I didn't see this one there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git ls-remote` (or `git remote show` but it's not directly useful here) can use the same Git protocols as `git clone` and `git fetch` to contact another Git.  These begin by getting a list of reference-to-hash mappings, e.g.:

```
8d7a455ed52e2a96debc080dfc011b6bb00db5d2        HEAD
a274e0a036ea886a31f8b216564ab1b4a3142f6c        refs/heads/maint
8d7a455ed52e2a96debc080dfc011b6bb00db5d2        refs/heads/master
fb549caa12ec67f9448f8f6b29b102ee5ec54c82        refs/heads/next
4b8cb2c9d27c63c844b1d2507b8b0981adfcf397        refs/heads/pu
595ca97928bf3cde17e40ecbbacb65cc3d053a06        refs/heads/todo
```

With clone and fetch, they go on to download any "interesting" objects, while `git ls-remote` simply prints them out and then stops.

See [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-remote.html) for options and additional details; note that the *repository* argument can be a URL, so you do not even need a clone to run in.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to directly do this using only Git locally.  If you are using a tool like Bitbucket or GitHub, then the website would show the latest commit hash in plain view.

One option to do this locally without having a lasting impact on anything would be to simply update your tracking branch.  But first, record what the commit hash of the tracking branch is.  So do this:

```
git log origin/master    # record the SHA-1 hash from HEAD
git pull origin master   # update the tracking branch
# find the SHA-1 hash you want
git update-ref refs/remotes/origin/master <original SHA-1 hash of origin/master>
```

The trick here is to reset the tracking branch to the point where it was when you started.  Now you have the hash you want.

But question: What use is this hash if you don't have a tracking branch containing the corresponding commits?

Comment: The use is complicated. Long story short it's for a software auto-update system that uses git commit hashes for update checks. The system is structured so only the update server accesses git (client devices go through the update server, non-git -- the server pulls, copies to a staging area, sanitizes, and makes that available to clients), and server-side git pulls are manually triggered. I'm trying to construct a status page on the server that shows the update server's current repo version but also the git server's latest version.