# How to get sha of current git commit from R

Tags: r, git, rstudio, r-markdown, sha

Is there a way to get SHA of current GIT commit from R? I need to access it via a function call (not as a hard string).

I have adapted GIT as version control system for analysis, and want to print the SHA on footnote of my intermediate reports (my working drafts, in pdf format, get a life of their own and it is not immediately obvious by looking at them at what moment they were generated; this creates a reproducibility issue).

For reference: I am using R 3.4.1 via R Studio and creating reports via r markdown.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll need to invoke the `git rev-parse` command as explained here: [How to retrieve the hash for the current commit in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949314/how-to-retrieve-the-hash-for-the-current-commit-in-git)

You can do it using `system()`:

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html

Putting it together:

```
system("git rev-parse HEAD", intern=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 9):

Install `git2r` package and then:

```
> library(git2r)
> r = revparse_single(path,"HEAD")
> sha(r)
[1] "f5bb1f115e9db0c732840298465488e8dfea5032"
```

It also gives you some other info about the commit too, in other members of the returned object:

```
> r$author
name:  Barry Rowlingson
email: b.rowlingson@lancs.ac.uk
when:  2022-01-12 18:37:14 GMT
```

These are documented in `help(commit)`, but only `sha` seems to have an accessor function for it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out an interesting package; it is a bit of an overkill for the task I had in mind, but it could come handy in the future.

Comment: I think it might now be `r$sha` instead of `r@sha`, as `r` is "not an S4 object".

Comment: @shabbychef thanks, the NEWS file tells me it switched to S3 in 2018! I've edited.