# How to print the latest commit ID from the git repo using shell script

Tags: git, shell, repo

I have the following shell script in linux environment, in which arr has the list of git repo paths and when I tried running this script, I am getting into that path through the line 3, but I am not able to get the latest commit ID and save in the variable, what I am missing in this code and how to get that commit ID in that variable "commit_ID".

```
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
 cd $i
 echo $i
 commit_ID = git log -1
 echo $commit_ID
done
```

Comment: Try changing commit_ID line to `commit_ID=git log -n1`. Put backticks before git and after 1. See if that works. You might also want to do a `cd ..` before `done` to return to the parent directory.

Comment: Rather `commit_ID=$( git log -n1 )`, no white spaces around the =.

Comment: It is just printing a blank line, when I tried commit_ID = ``git log -n1``

Comment: And about the cd, I guess it should be `cd -`, so that it went out to whatever path it was before (the parameter might be comprised of 2 directories... or an absolute path or what not).

Comment: Don't use `cd`. Try `commit_ID=$(git --git-dir=$i/.git log -n1)` instead. If `$i` is a bare repo, don't append `/.git`.

Comment: Thanks @eftshift0, it worked when I tried like commit_ID=$( git log -n1 ) , thanks others for your suggestions.

Answer (score 12):

Instead of `git log -n1`, you could [instead use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/949391/6309):

```
COMMIT_ID=$(git rev-parse --verify HEAD)
```